# Differentiating between arrays and "hashes" in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In order to make the syntax for one of my functions nicer, I need to be able to tell whether a specific parameter is an array or "hash" (which I know are just objects).

Typeof doesn't work, because they both return the same thing

`typeof {foo:"bar"} // Object`

`typeof ["foo","bar"] // Object`

So how would I differentiate between the two?

I know this *works*, but I'm hoping there's a nicer way

`({foo:"bar"}).constructor // Object()`

`(["foo","bar"]).constructor // [ undefined ]`

**EDIT**
Ah, it seems [ undefined ] in firebug is the same thing as Array. Kind of weird.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could check the length property as SLaks suggested, but as soon as you pass it a function object you'll be surprised, because it in fact has a length property. Also if the object has a length property defined, you'll get wrong result again.

Your best bet is probably:

```
function isArray(obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Array]";
}
```

jQuery uses it, and a "couple of" other people... :)

It is more fail proof than the instanceof way. The method is also suggested by the following article:

**['instanceof' considered harmful (or how to write a robust 'isArray')](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/) *(@kagax)***

Another thing to add that this function is almost identical to the `Array.isArray` function in ES 5 spec:

> **15.4.3.2   Array.isArray ( arg )**
>
> 1. If Type(*arg*) is not Object, return
>      **false**.
> 2. If the value of the [[Class]]
>      internal property of *arg* is **"Array"**,
>      then return **true**.
> 3. Return **false**.

Comment: Good article showing how instanceof may fail when using iframes.

Comment: Lots of good answers, but this looks like the best way. Thanks for the reference too.

Comment: np :) thank to @kangax btw. I'm kinda curious if jQuery changed it's code to this method because of the article though... :)

Comment: For me, it only works if I do `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)`, as in the reference. toString.call(obj) return `[xpconnect wrapped native prototype]`

Comment: The example is nicked from jQuery, which puts `Object.prototype.toString` in the variable `toString` for some reason. It won't work as-is.

Comment: @bobince +1 thank God, you live.. :) I always forget stuff. And "some reason" is probably that it's faster (less lookup) and shorter.

Comment: In the comments to kangax's article is the fact that this doesn't work for arrays in pop-up windows, and a link to the following discussion: https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/browse_frm/thread/368a55fec19af7b2/efea4aa2d12a3aa4?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=+An+isArray+test+%28and+IE+bugs%29+#efea4aa2d12a3aa4

Answer (score 7):

`something instanceof Array` works fine within a single document, but will fail if you start passing arrays between different windows, because the `Array` from one window is a different object from `Array` on another. If you have no intention of doing cross-window-scripting (and in general, it's worth avoiding) I would recommend sticking with this.

If you need cross-window support, things are a bit more complex. In the future the story is simple, as ECMAScript Fifth Edition defines a function to do exactly this:

```
Array.isArray([1]);   // -> true
```

You should use this functionality where available as it's the only reliable and standards-endorsed way. However, many of today's browsers don't support it yet.

Where it isn't available you have to rely on `Object#toString` serialisation, which is ugly and slightly dodgy. Although it will in general work reliably with today's browsers, there are imaginable cases where it might not (primarily to do with host objects).

You can hack this fallback method into `Array` on browsers that don't support it, and then use `Array.isArray` at all times:

```
if (!('isArray' in Array)) {
    Array.isArray= function(o) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(o)==='[object Array]';
    };
}
```

As for `constructor`, never use it. It's not available everywhere and it doesn't do what you think. Using it is almost always a mistake.

Comment: bobince: +1 *Thank you* for the note on not using `constructor`. Much appreciated. I deleted my answer.

Comment: This is more than slightly dodgy: you don't need to imagine anything more outlandish than an array from a pop-up window for it to go wrong. See https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/browse_frm/thread/368a55fec19af7b2/efea4aa2d12a3aa4?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=+An+isArray+test+%28and+IE+bugs%29+#efea4aa2d12a3aa4

Answer (score 3):

I think the most elegant way is to simply use the `instanceof` operator:

```
if (myVar instanceof Array)
    doSomething();
```

examples:

```
[] instanceof Array           // true
{} instanceof Array           // false
{length:100} instanceof Array // false
null instanceof Array         // false
```

#### Edit:

Be aware that it will fail when testing an object from another iFrame (see answers by @galambalazs and @bobince)

Comment: Agreed, it handles array subclasses, can't be faked with various properties, and doesn't resort to string comparisons.

Comment: This is cleanest if you don't need cross-window scripting support.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the `length` property:

```
"length" in {foo:"bar"}   //false
"length" in ["foo","bar"] //true
```

Comment: `"length in {foo:"bar", length:"baz"}`  // true`

Comment: -1 unfortunately function objects will ruin this, see my answer... + what Chadwick said

Comment: I don't get @Chadwick's result. Far as I can tell, this is correct, yet it is down voted.

Comment: A hash (object) can have a `length` property as seen in my comment above. I think @galambalazs is referring to creating a class with a `length` function, which would be equivalent. Just because an object has a `length` property, does not mean it's an Array.

Comment: @Chadwick - I see what you mean. I didn't look closely enough at your code example. Makes sense.

Comment: @Chadwick `"I think @galambalazs is referring to creating a class with a length function,"` - definetely not. :) *1.)* There are no classes in the language. *2.)* I said a **function object** like `function f(a){}` then try `alert(f.length)` it will be one(1). *3.)* **functions** are in fact **first-class** objects in this language

Comment: @galambalaze js objects behave close to Classes, with prototype based inheritance, constructors, and by using things like jQuery's `.extend` one can even test if those 'extensions' are `instanceof` the 'parent object' - but no, they are not Classes. Yep, Functions are Objects, so you could assign a `length` property to them as well. Whether the `Function` is the object or the property is irrelevant, we agree - I merely misread your example.

Answer (score 0):

This typeof function is used to correct the array/object clash for the typeof operator, *and* the null/object clash. It does not however work across frames or across windows. See the source for a more advanced version that works across these.

```
function typeOf(value) {
    var s = typeof value;
    if (s === 'object') {
        if (value) {
            if (value instanceof Array) {
                s = 'array';
            }
        } else {
            s = 'null';
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Source: [Douglas Crockford's Javascript site](http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html)