# typeof for RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, constructor, instanceof, typeof

Is there anyway to detect if a JavaScript object is a regex?

For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
var t = /^foo(bar)?$/i;
alert(typeof t); //I want this to return "regexp"
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks for all the answers. It seems I have two very good choices:

```
obj.constructor.name === "RegExp"
```

or

```
obj instanceof RegExp
```

Any major pros/cons to either method?

Thanks again!

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215046/differentiating-between-arrays-and-hashes-in-javascript/3215440#3215440) to another question for concerns with the use of `instanceof` and `constructor`.

Comment: Hi, I don't think putting answers in your question is very relevant. Please consider to add your own answer if you think you can add something useful :)

Answer (score 255, accepted):

You can use **instanceof** operator:

```
var t = /^foo(bar)?$/i;
alert(t instanceof RegExp);//returns true
```

In fact, that is *almost* the same as:

```
var t = /^foo(bar)?$/i;
alert(t.constructor == RegExp);//returns true
```

Keep in mind that as **RegExp** is not a [primitive data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wkd9z69(v=vs.94).aspx), it is not possible to use `typeof` operator which could [be the best option](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) for this question.

But you can use this trick above or others like *[duck type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing) checking*, for example, checking if such object has any vital methods or properties, or by its *internal class value* (by using `{}.toString.call(instaceOfMyObject)`).

Comment: awesome. do you know which is faster/more compatible: using your instanceof method or the constructor.name method? thanks!

Comment: instanceof, of course, you can verify it yourself using Firebug Timing(console.time)

Comment: Those two code snippets are not identical. If you inserted the line `t.constructor = function() {};`, which is perfectly legal, then `t instanceof RegExp` will still be true but `t.constructor == RegExp` will be false. Using `instanceof` is therefore preferable.

Comment: Also, `t instanceof RegExp` will report false when testing a regular expression object from another window, which won't be a problem if this kind of check is not required, but is something to be aware of.

Comment: Also, when using in "if/else if" and you checked before for (typeof t === 'object') : add either -> && !(_t instanceof RegExp) to this check or if possible perform Cleiton's check first. [tl;dr : it is also typeof object, just important if used in "if/else if" ...]

Answer (score 24):

```
alert( Object.prototype.toString.call( t ) ); // [object RegExp]
```

This is the way mentioned in the specification for getting the class of object.

From **ECMAScript 5, Section 8.6.2 Object Internal Properties and Methods**:

> The value of the [[Class]] internal property is defined by this specification for every kind of built-in object. The value of the [[Class]] internal property of a host object may be any String value except one of **"Arguments", "Array", "Boolean", "Date", "Error", "Function", "JSON", "Math", "Number", "Object", "RegExp", and "String"**. The value of a [[Class]] internal property is used internally to distinguish different kinds of objects. Note that this specification does not provide any means for a program to access that value except through Object.prototype.toString (see 15.2.4.2).

A RegExp is a class of object defined in the spec at **Section 15.10 RegExp(RegularExpression)Objects**:

> A RegExp object contains a regular expression and the associated flags.

Comment: @Tim - I'm pretty sure. Not that it's any guarantee, but it is the [method jQuery uses](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L504-508), including for [RegExp](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L821-823). I'll just did a quick test in IE6 using a RegExp, and it does work (if that's any indicator). :o) Appears as though this method made it into the spec in the 3rd edition.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in IE with RegExp objects from other windows, for the same reason that the `[object Array]` check doesn't work for arrays. See http://www.jsfiddle.net/F6d8u/ for a demo and https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/browse_frm/thread/368a55fec19af7b2/efea4aa2d12a3aa4?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=+An+isArray+test+%28and+IE+bugs%29+#efea4aa2d12a3aa4 for a discussion of this.

Comment: Apart from duck typing, which is irritatingly inexact, this is still the best answer.

Comment: @Tim - Interesting. I'm going to take a closer look at the example and article in a little bit when I have a chance to fire up IE again. Thanks for the input.

Comment: In Node.js it returns `[object String]` so it's not helpful... Possibly because it's across contexts.

Answer (score 14):

Give the `.constructor` property a whirl:

```
> /^foo(bar)?$/i.constructor
function RegExp() { [native code] }
> /^foo(bar)?$/i.constructor.name
"RegExp"
> /^foo(bar)?$/i.constructor == RegExp
true
```

Comment: The `constructor` property can be changed. `instanceof` does not have this problem and is a better solution.

Comment: @TimDown, true, but `instanceof` won't work across execution contexts.

Comment: In contrast, anyone can construct an object whose `.constructor` has that name.

Answer (score 11):

From [underscore.js](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L621)

```
// Is the given value a regular expression?
  _.isRegExp = function(obj) {
    return !!(obj && obj.test && obj.exec && (obj.ignoreCase || obj.ignoreCase === false));
  };
```

Comment: They're duck typing here because `typeof` is unreliable for regexes and `instanceof` suffers from the cross-window problem. I wonder why they're not using @patrick dw's answer...

Comment: Now I know: it doesn't work in IE when examining objects from other windows.

Comment: @Tim -- awesome ... I was wondering the same thing, but didn't have time to check yet.  Thanks for posting the answer here!

Comment: Underscore now uses `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == '[object RegExp]'`

Answer (score 3):

Works in google chrome:

```
x = /^foo(bar)?$/i;
x == RegExp(x); // true
y = "hello";
y == RegExp(y); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

"Regexp" is not a native Javascript type. Most of the above answers tell you how to accomplish your task, but not why. Here's [why](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator).

Comment: That's a misleading answer. A regular expression most definitely is a native ECMAScript and JavaScript object. I think what you're getting at is that typeof's possible values do not include a dedicated value for regular expression.

Comment: `sed -i s/native/primitive/`.  If you count `object` as primitive, `typeof t` only outputs the primitive type name (well. mostly.  see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Answer (score 0):

There is no absolute way of checking this, so far the best answer is

```
var t = /^foo(bar)?$/i;
alert(t instanceof RegExp);//returns true
```

but there is one down side to this approach and that's it will return false if the regular expression object is commeing from an other window.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways:

```
/^\/.*\/$/.test(/hi/) /* test regexp literal via regexp literal */
/^\/.*\/$/.test(RegExp("hi") ) /* test RegExp constructor via regexp literal */
RegExp("^/" + ".*" + "/$").test(/hi/) /* test regexp literal via RegExp constructor */
RegExp("^/" + ".*" + "/$").test(RegExp("hi") ) /* test RegExp constructor via RegExp constructor */ 

delete RegExp("hi").source /* test via deletion of the source property */
delete /hi/.global /* test via deletion of the global property */
delete /hi/.ignoreCase /* test via deletion of the ignoreCase property */
delete RegExp("hi").multiline /* test via deletion of the multiline property */
delete RegExp("hi").lastIndex /* test via deletion of the lastIndex property */
```

If a string literal is delimited by the regexp backslash delimiter, the regexp self test will fail.

If `Object.seal` or `Object.freeze` are run on a user-defined object, and that object also has all of the aforementioned properties, the `delete` statement will return a false positive.

**References**

- [ECMAScript 5, Section 15.10.4.1 new RegExp(pattern, flags)](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es5#sec-15.10.4.1)
- [What are some use-cases of when `delete` has been very useful in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16951655/1113772)
- [Why is this configurable property not deletable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044212/)
- [Webkit JavaScriptCore source: ObjectConstructor.cpp](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/JavaScriptCore/runtime/ObjectConstructor.cpp)
- [Object Properties in JavaScript](http://2ality.com/2012/10/javascript-properties.html)

Comment: I do not understand your answer.

Comment: @Tino RegExp types have two unique characteristics.  The literal values start and end with the `/` character. The constructor instances have the `source`, `global`, `ignoreCase`, `multiline`, and `lastIndex` properties.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately following `frog` proves that these characteristics are **not unique** to `RegExp`s: `$$=function(){};$$.prototype.toString=function(){return "/I am not a duck^WRegExp/"};$$.prototype.source=$$.prototype.global=$$.prototype.ignoreCase=$$.prototype.multiline=$$.prototype.lastIndex="quack"; frog=new $$()`

Comment: @Tino That's why the `delete` keyword was used. If you `delete` them from an instance of a `RegExp` object, you will get a different result than if you delete them from a custom object or any other built-in which is customized. See an [unrelated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193412/what-are-some-use-cases-of-when-delete-has-been-very-useful-in-javascript/16951655#16951655) for further explanation.