# What are some use-cases of when `delete` has been very useful in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, memory-management

We have some questions here that discuss delete in a more abstracted way, but I'm looking for practical examples of when use of `delete` could be used, versus doing something such as setting the property to null or undefined.

[The delete operator deletes a property of an object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/delete)

What's a case of a challenge faced somewhere, that `delete` was the best solution, versus something else?

Comment: After reading "JavaScript: the first 20 years" https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3386327 I got the feeling that delete was added as a supplementary purpose because properties may be dynamically added, so they should be able to deleted too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "Incognito", {
  get: function() { return 42; },
  set: function() { },
  configurable: true
});

console.log(({}).Incognito); // 42
({}).Incognito = null;
console.log(({}).Incognito); // 42

// I DO NOT WANT INCOGNITO
delete Object.prototype.Incognito
console.log(({}).Incognito); // undefined
```

Any property which has an empty setter (Because someone thought *that* was a good idea) needs to be deleted if you want to get rid of it.

```
var hash = {
  "FALSE": undefined,
  "TRUE": null
}

console.log("TRUE" in hash); // true
console.log("FALSE" in hash); // true
delete hash.FALSE;
console.log("FALSE" in hash); // false
```

The `in` operator returns `true` for any property that exist no matter it's value. If you want it to return `false` you need to `delete` the property.

In both these cases setting it to `null` or `undefined` does nothing (Because it either has a setter that does nothing, or that's how the `in` operator works)

Comment: I don't get it. Whats the point there ? The question was concerned about application logic (as far as I got it). So the question is still open, whats the benefit of using `delete` and not just `null`ing the variable/property.

Comment: @jAndy sorry the point was that nulling it doesn't work. I've made it slightly more clear.

Comment: uhhh, that came in pretty late into the answer. The first version (just the `.defineProperty`) didn't make much sense.

Comment: @jAndy I kind of expected you to extend fill the dots yourself.

Comment: no way to get that on the first version. However, it's fine now ;)

Answer (score 4):

When using an object as a hashmap, you can iterate over the object's properties using:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    // ...
}
```

If some properties of that objects were set to `null`, their keys would be included there. By using `delete` you can remove their keys completely.

Answer (score 1):

Setting an object's property to `null` or `undefined` will still leave the property as enumerable - if you're going to do a `for..in` over the object at any stage and the presence of a property is significant, this is when you'd want to `delete` instead.

For example, if you have one constructor which takes arguments as an object, which inherits from another constructor which does the same and the presence of a property is significant when calling the parent constructor (say, in the example below, that ParentWidgets used its arguments with a `for..in` to generate HTML attributes) you would want to use `delete` to remove properties which aren't relevant to the parent:

```
function ChildWidget(kwargs) {
  kwargs = extend({
    childSpecific1: null, childSpecific2: 42
  }, kwargs || {})
  this.childSpecific1 = kwargs.childSpecific1
  this.childSpecific2 = kwargs.childSpecific2
  delete kwargs.childSpecific1
  delete kwargs.childSpecific2
  ParentWidget.call(this, kwargs)
}
inherits(ChildWidget, ParentWidget)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `delete` operator is useful in a reset or clear method for removing object literal data tied to forms:

```
delete formmap["forms"]
```

It is also useful for deleting objects tied to state:

```
/* lights... */
if (node["alpha"+i].active)
  {
  // camera, action
  node["beta"+i] = chi;
  }
else
  {
  /* cut! */
  delete node["beta"+i];
  node["omega"].state = false;
  }
```

In addition, it's useful as a shorthand for inlining optional object properties:

```
var foo = {"bar": [], "drink": [], "tab": [] }

// happy hour
this.bar && (foo["bar"]).push(this.bar) || delete foo.bar;
// open a tab
this.drink && (foo["drink"]).push(this.drink) || delete foo.drink;
// cheers
this.tab && (foo["tab"]).push(this.tab) || delete foo.tab;
```

Finally, it's useful as a way to distinguish between types by using the writable permissions of type specific instance properties as a litmus test:

```
// Function
!!foo.prototype === true && delete foo.length === false && delete foo[-1] === true

// Object, Number, Infinity, or Boolean (probably Object)
!!foo.prototype === false && delete foo.length === true && delete foo[-1] === true

// Array
!!foo.prototype === false && delete foo.length === false && delete foo[-1] === true

// String
!!foo.prototype === false && delete foo.length === false && delete foo[-1] === false

// RegExp
delete foo.source === false
```

**References**

- [Adobe Flash Platform: delete statement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118cd9b5f6e-79cb.html)
- [JScript Reference: Delete Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as11h77s)