# How to tell if an object is a RegExp object?

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [typeof for RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339288/typeof-for-regexp)

I have a routine that is testing to see if an object matches given criteria.

```
testForMatch(objectToTest, matchCriteria) {
    // all my testing logic here.
}
```

The parameter `matchCriteria` is an object that could look like this, for example:

```
{
    'size'     : "large",
    'color'    : /(blue|red)/
}
```

This `matchCriteria` in the above example will be used to test if `objectToTest` has an attribute `size` with value `"large"`, and an attribute `color` with value of either `"blue"` or `"red"`.

So `matchCriteria` has property/attribute names that will be sought in `objectToTest` with the goal of matching the values of the properties. Or, if a regex is given as the value (as in the case of `color` above) the property in `objectToTest` will be `RegExp.test()`'ed against the given regex.

But in order to treat the `matchCriteria` properly in `testForMatch()`, I need to be able to tell if the value of an attribute in `matchCriteria` is a string or a `RegExp` object.

My question is, how can I detect if the value of an attribute is a `RegExp` object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339288/typeof-for-regexp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

how about

```
var o = {
    'size' : "large",
    'color': /(blue|red)/
}

console.log( o['color'] instanceof RegExp )

>>true
```

Comment: Ah! Yes. Thanks. I'll accept when the timer lets me.