# Why is this configurable property not deletable?

Tags: javascript, properties, language-lawyer, ecma262

Configurable properties seem to be deletable:

```js
var o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, 'prop', {
    configurable: true,
    value: 'val'
});
delete o.prop; // true
o.prop;        // undefined
```

But it doesn't work in the following case, at least on Firefox and Chrome:

```js
var form = document.createElement('form'),
    input = document.createElement('input');
form.appendChild(input);
var elems = form.elements;
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(form, 0)
      .configurable; // true <────────────────────── !!!
delete elems[0];     // false                         │
elems[0];            // input                         │
(function(){ 'use strict'; //                         V
    delete elems[0]; // TypeError: property 0 is non-configurable
})();                // and can't be deleted
```

But this seems to contradict the spec.

The `delete` operator is defined like this:

> [**11.4.1 - The delete Operator**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.1)
>
> The production *UnaryExpression* : `delete` *UnaryExpression* is
>   evaluated as follows:
>
> - Let *ref* be the result of evaluating *UnaryExpression*.
> - [...]
> - If [IsPropertyReference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7)(*ref*) is **true**, then
>
>   - Return the result of calling the [[Delete]] internal method on [ToObject](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.9)([GetBase](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7)(*ref*)) providing
>       [GetReferencedName](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7)(*ref*) and [IsStrictReference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7)(*ref*) as the
>       arguments.

So the result of using `delete` depends on [[Delete]]. Now let's see what [[Delete]] does:

> [**8.12.7 - [[Delete]] (P, Throw)**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.3)
>
> When the [[Delete]] internal method of *O* is called with property
>   name *P* and the Boolean flag *Throw*, the following steps are taken:
>
> - Let *desc* be the result of calling the [[GetOwnProperty]] internal method of *O* with property name *P*.
> - If *desc* is **undefined**, then return **true**.
> - If *desc*.[[Configurable]] is **true**, then
>
>   - Remove the own property with name *P* from *O*.
>   - Return **true**.
> - Else if *Throw*, then throw a **TypeError** exception.
> - Return **false**.

Therefore, if the property is configurable, it should be deletable.

But wait, maybe `Object.getOwnPropertyDescritor` is a troll and says that a property is configurable, but [[Configurable]] is **false**. Let's see:

> [**15.2.3.3 - Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor ( O, P )**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.3)
>
> When the **getOwnPropertyDescriptor** function is called, the
>   following steps are taken:
>
> - If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(*O*) is not Object throw a **TypeError** exception.
> - Let *name* be [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8)(*P*).
> - Let *desc* be the result of calling the [[GetOwnProperty]] internal method of *O* with argument *name*.
> - Return the result of calling [FromPropertyDescriptor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10.4)(*desc*).

So it also uses [[GetOwnProperty]], like [[Delete]]. Maybe the troll is FromPropertyDescriptor?

> [**8.10.4 FromPropertyDescriptor ( Desc )**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10.4)
>
> When the abstract operation FromPropertyDescriptor is called with
>   property descriptor *Desc*, the following steps are taken:
>
> - If *Desc* is **undefined**, then return **undefined**.
> - Let *obj* be the result of creating a new object as if by the expression **new Object()** where **Object** is the standard built-in
>     constructor with that name.
> - ...
> - Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *obj* with arguments "`configurable`", [Property Descriptor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10) {[[Value]]:
>     *Desc*.[[Configurable]], [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]: **true**, [[Configurable]]: **true**}, and **false**.
> - Return *obj*.

So no, it is not a troll neither. The `configurable` property of the property descriptor is set to the [[Configurable]] value.

How is it possible, then, that a configurable property can't be deleted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Effectively, configurable properties are deletable.

But there is a big problem: that only applies to [native objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.6), but not to [host objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.8).

As explained in [8.6.2 - Object Internal Properties and Methods](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2),

> Host objects may support these internal properties with any
>   implementation-dependent behaviour as long as it is consistent with
>   the specific host object restrictions stated in this document.

For those, [[GetOwnProperty]] must behave differently:

> If a property is described as a data property and it may return
>   different values over time, then either or both of the [[Writable]]
>   and [[Configurable]] attributes must be **true** even if no mechanism
>   to change the value is exposed via the other internal methods.

In your example, [`form.elements`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-elements) is a [`HTMLFormControlsCollection`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#htmlformcontrolscollection-0) instance defined by the HTML spec, so it's a host object.

Therefore, the situation is

- It has a custom [[GetOwnProperty]] which says that the property `'0'` is configurable because its value may change.
- It also has a custom [[Delete]] which doesn't delete the property, even if [[GetOwnProperty]] says it's configurable.