# Assert that a property is not configurable

Tags: javascript, object, properties, assert

Given an object `obj`, how can I assert that its property `prop` is not configurable?

First, I thought I could use `getOwnPropertyDescriptor`:

```js
if(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop).configurable)
    throw Error('The property is configurable');
```

But that isn't foolproof, because it could have been modified:

```js
var getDescr = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor;
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor = function() {
    var ret = getDescr.apply(this, arguments);
    ret.configurable = false;
    return ret;
};
```

Is there a foolproof way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `obj` is a [native object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.6) (this may be unreliable for [host objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.8), see [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29044212/1529630)), you can use the [`delete` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.1).

When `delete` is used with an object property, it returns the result of calling the [[[Delete]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.7) internal method.

And [[Delete]] will return `true` if the property is configurable. Otherwise, it will throw a `TypeError` in strict mode, or will return `false` in non-strict mode.

Therefore, to assert that `prop` is non-configurable,

- In non-strict mode:

  ```js
  function assertNonConfigurable(obj, prop) {
      if(delete obj[prop])
          throw Error('The property is configurable');
  }
  ```
- In strict mode:

  ```js
  function assertNonConfigurable(obj, prop) {
      'use strict';
      try {
          delete obj[prop];
      } catch (err) {
          return;
      }
      throw Error('The property is configurable');
  }
  ```

Of course, if the property is configurable, it will be deleted. Therefore, you can use this to assert, but not to check whether it is configurable or not.