# Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, null, comparison, undefined

Is there a universal JavaScript function that checks that a variable has a value and ensures that it's not `undefined` or `null`? I've got this code, but I'm not sure if it covers all cases:

```
function isEmpty(val){
    return (val === undefined || val == null || val.length <= 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: I made a fiddle for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/J7m7m/886/

Comment: Protip, never do `(truthy statement) ? true : false;`. Just do `(truthy statement);`.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty not a dup, since the other answer asks about _strings_ in particular, whereas this one asks about _variables_.

Comment: Any correct answer to this question relies entirely on how you define "blank".

Comment: falsy values in javascript with example : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: @David out of curiosity, why not? I've used both with no apparent ill effects.

Comment: @Jay It doesn't hurt anything as far as execution of your code. It's just overly verbose. You wouldn't say, "Is are you hungry is true?" You just "Are you hungry" So in code just say `if (hungry) …` instead of `if (hungry === true) …`. Like all coding things in this manner, it's just a matter of taste. More specific to the example provided by the OP he's saying even more verbosely, "If it's true, then true, if not then false" But if it's true, then it's already true. And, if it's false, it's already false. This is akin to saying "If you're hungry then you are, and if not then you aren't."

Comment: If you want to force a value to be a real boolean, you can do `!!value`. It's just the "not" operator twice, so it reads like "not not value", which is its boolean value.

Comment: @frodo2975, thanks. Didn’t know you can convert a value to a Boolean this way in JavaScript. That’s the same as C++. Interesting

Comment: The correct answer relies on how you define false as said. To deal with the false is:
`function isEmpty(val) { return (val || val === false) }`

Comment: This become fail when input is boolean.

Comment: wouldn't if(variable == null || variable.length <= 0) do the trick?
undefined  results in TRUE
null results in TRUE
[] results in TRUE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check for an empty/undefined/null string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-i-check-for-an-empty-undefined-null-string-in-javascript)

Comment: A question’s grounds for being a duplicate is not decided by the question itself, but the answers to it. If two questions lead to the same answers, despite being somewhat different, they are indeed duplicates. You may blame the design of JS for why these two questions have the same answers.

Comment: I do this at beginning of page and dont need to deal with any of that... const orderTotal = order?.Total ?? 0;  This way it will return 0 instead of null of undefined. Do the same for string.

Comment: The dup question was about checking empty strings, all original answers were about strings. IDK why someone back in 2015 added the words undefined, null, empty in the title and now that whole question is a hodgepodge. Now if this question is a "duplicate" then I suggest we merge both questions.

Answer (score 5723, accepted):

You can just check if the *variable* has a `truthy` value or not. That means

```
if (value) {
    // do something..
}
```

will evaluate to `true` if `value` is **not**:

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty string ("")
- 0
- false

The above list represents all possible `falsy` values in ECMA-/Javascript. Find it in the [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2) at the `ToBoolean` section.

Furthermore, if you do not **know** whether a variable exists (that means, if it was *declared*) you should check with the `typeof` operator. For instance

```
if (typeof foo !== 'undefined') {
    // foo could get resolved and it's defined
}
```

If you can be sure that a *variable* is declared at least, you should directly check if it has a `truthy` value like shown above.

Comment: What if the value is a false boolean that was intended. Sometimes you want to give a default value if there is no value, which won't work if false boolean was passed in.

Comment: @TruMan1: in such a case (where your logic dictates the validation) you have to go like `if( value || value === false )`. Same goes for all *falsy values*, we need to validate for those explicitly.

Comment: Except if value is an array. The interpretation of `truthy` could be misleading. In that case we should be checking `value.length != 0` for a non-empty array.

Comment: Just want to add that if you feel the `if` construct is syntactically too heavy, you could use the ternary operator, like so: `var result = undefined ? "truthy" : "falsy"`. Or if you just want to coerce to a boolean value, use the `!!` operator, e.g. `!!1 // true`, `!!null // false`.

Comment: Also note that this will not check for strings which only contain whitespace characters.

Comment: Another interesting fact: only NaN variable is not equal to itself. i.e. if you need to check specifically if a variable is NaN then use (var !== var).
```var x = NaN;
x !== x (true)```

Comment: Another reason to check if length is greater than 0 (in addition to the array check mentioned by @buffer), is that " " (a space) is not considered 'truthy' but it is conceptually blank.

Comment: Be aware that this will produce undesired results if `0` is actually an okay `value` (which it is in most cases where some integer or decimal value is to be stored in `value`).

Comment: any IE10 version of this?

Comment: `typeof` is no longer safe in ES6. You get a `ReferenceError` if you typdef a variable declared with `let` or `const` later in the scope. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/3242070

Comment: This is a really simple answer that will lead to a lot of false positives. You need to be more specific when checking values.

Comment: apparently the latest fashion is to test for undefined against `(void 0)` as undefined may well be a legitimate variable in scope.

Comment: I wonder if this reference to "truthiness" predates Stephen Colbert's coinage of the term?

Comment: I find the syntax someone difficult to understand: I'm used to seeing something like `if(empty(value)){//value is empty}`. Good to know though

Comment: There seems to be correction in this answer 
var a;
if(a){console.log('I am undefined"');}
Prints "I am undefined" in console, where as typeof(a) is still undefined

Comment: This is all well and good, unless you are checking for a numeric value, which can include 0. Just a heads up, as it may, at some point, bite you right on the ass, just like it did for me today. I was checking for the existence of a variable retrieved from an endpoint (json) and doing a price calculation. The price was 0. My code thus failed, as 0 in my case was a valid value.

Comment: Does the "0" mean it will check for array length? I'm working on some inherited JS and there are a lot of checks for NULL and variable.length > 0. I know truthy with get the NULL but does it also check an array variable having a length?

Comment: No, not at all. Checking like `if( array_name )` will always be `true` if `array_name` references anything. That includes an empty array (object). Short: The condition will just check the reference, not the content, so you have to check for `array_name.length` explicitly if you need to know if there are any elements contained by that js-array.

Comment: I ran across this answer and kept using this solution, until I had a _0_ value not triggering an if. The "0" exception should be in bold.

Comment: If the value is either empty object `{}` or empty array `[]` this will return `true`.

Comment: undefined values resolve as undefined in this case, not false

Comment: The answer is partially wrong. If you have const value = '' and do if (!value) it will evaluate to true even without a value. Although you can do shorthand, shorthand becomes quite confusing in large scale projects where you need to know what the expected fail value should be when reading code. Shorthand is painful when working with projects you didn't write yourself.

Comment: This is definitely what you don't want to do, it will return true too often. Definite javascript mistake.

Comment: See python. Even `[]` will test as `false`. This is a choice of course as you can still use `==` for values or `is` in some cases (not going to explain this last one here though)

Comment: How to include test for an empty object? const emptyObject = {}, will return true if tested.

Comment: I cant believe this answer got 4000 votes and marked as correct. null, undefined and false(y) are not the same.

Comment: Also remember that !!"0" === true, sometimes it sneaks in like when you get it from <input>

Comment: what about "null"?

Comment: in es6
     val?doSomthing():null;

Comment: 0 is pretty much always considered defined and the most common source of bugs with this type of code. Seen it way too many times.

Comment: this method dont work if the variable is zero (0)

Comment: @fcaserio The value `0` is mentioned in the original post.

Comment: what about the opposite check?

Comment: Does nobody get an undefined error in the console? or you're simply ignoring it? I'm getting a Reference error XXX is not defined. Which is precisely why I always have to resort to the typeof call

Comment: This answer is not a valid solution to the original question. The question asked for a way to test if a variable does not have a value assigned (null or undefined).  This answer will return true for any of 0, '', or [] which does not address the question.

Answer (score 382):

> This question has two interpretations:
>
> Check if the variable has a value
> Check if the variable has a truthy value
>
> The following answers both.

In JavaScript, a value could be [nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish) or not nullish, and a value could be [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) or [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).
Nullish values are a proper subset of falsy values:

```
 ╭─ nullish ──────╮ ╭─ not nullish ─────────────────────────────────╮
┌───────────┬──────┬───────┬───┬────┬─────┬──────┬───┬─────────┬─────┐
│ undefined │ null │ false │ 0 │ "" │ ... │ true │ 1 │ "hello" │ ... │
└───────────┴──────┴───────┴───┴────┴─────┴──────┴───┴─────────┴─────┘
 ╰─ falsy ───────────────────────────────╯ ╰─ truthy ───────────────╯
```

### Check if value is nullish (undefined or null)

Use one of the following depending on your coding style:

```
if (value == null)                         { /* value is nullish */ }
if (value === undefined || value === null) { /* value is nullish */ }
if (value == undefined)                    { /* value is nullish */ }
if ((value ?? null) === null)              { /* value is nullish */ }
```

Notes:

- The `==` operator works because [it has a special case for null vs undefined comparison](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-islooselyequal)
- The `===` operator is more readable (opinion based), eqeqeq friendly and allows checking for undefined and null separately
- The first and third examples work identically, however the third one is rarely seen in production code
- The fourth example uses nullish coalescing operator to change nullish values to `null` for straight forward comparison

### Check if value is not nullish

```
if (value != null)                         { /* value is not nullish, although it could be falsy */ }
if (value !== undefined && value !== null) { /* value is not nullish, although it could be falsy */ }
if (value != undefined)                    { /* value is not nullish, although it could be falsy */ }
if ((value ?? null) !== null)              { /* value is not nullish, although it could be falsy */ }
```

### Check if value is falsy

Use the [`!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT) operator:

```
if (!value) { /* value is falsy */ }
```

### Check if value is truthy

```
if (value) { /* value is truthy */ }
```

### Data validation

The nullish, falsy and truthy checks cannot be used for data validation on their own. For example, `0` (falsy) is valid age of a person and `-1` (truthy) is not. Additional logic needs to be added on case-by-case basis. Some examples:

```js
/*
 * check if value is greater than/equal to 0
 * note that we cannot use truthy check here because 0 must be allowed
 */
[null, -1, 0, 1].forEach(num => {
  if (num != null && num >= 0) {
    console.log("%o is not nullish and greater than/equal to 0", num);
  } else {
    console.log("%o is bad", num);
  }
});

/*
 * check if value is not empty-or-whitespace string
 */
[null, "", " ", "hello"].forEach(str => {
  if (str && /\S/.test(str)) {
    console.log("%o is truthy and has non-whitespace characters", str);
  } else {
    console.log("%o is bad", str);
  }
});

/*
 * check if value is not an empty array
 * check for truthy before checking the length property
 */
[null, [], [1]].forEach(arr => {
  if (arr && arr.length) {
    console.log("%o is truthy and has one or more items", arr);
  } else {
    console.log("%o is bad", arr);
  }
});

/*
 * check if value is not an empty array
 * using optional chaining operator to make sure that the value is not nullish
 */
[null, [], [1]].forEach(arr => {
  if (arr?.length) {
    console.log("%o is not nullish and has one or more items", arr);
  } else {
    console.log("%o is bad", arr);
  }
});
```

Comment: Checking for only `null` or `undefined` can be done like so:  `if (value == null)`. Mind the `==` operator that coerces. If you check like this `if (value === null || value === undefined)`, you forgot/don't know how Javascript coerces. http://webreflection.blogspot.nl/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek: your point that `arg == null` produces same results as `arg === undefined || arg === null`. However, I consider the latter example more readable.

Comment: `arg == null` is pretty common in my experience.

Comment: `return value === (void 0)` is safer than testing against `undefined` which may well be a legitimate variable in scope, sadly.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek then why this produces a reference error? https://jsfiddle.net/00rb295d/

Comment: @Sharky Because the variable is not declared. Use `typeof` if you don't even know if you declared the variable. See the accepted answer for more details.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek then your initial comment is wrong.

Comment: @Sharky There's a difference between a variable that is undefined and an undeclared variable: http://lucybain.com/blog/2014/null-undefined-undeclared/

Comment: Should mention the null coalescing operator `??`

Answer (score 133):

```
function isEmpty(value){
  return (value == null || value.length === 0);
}
```

This will return true for

```
undefined  // Because undefined == null

null

[]

""
```

and zero argument functions since a function's `length` is the number of declared parameters it takes.

To disallow the latter category, you might want to just check for blank strings

```
function isEmpty(value){
  return (value == null || value === '');
}
```

Null or whitespace

```
function isEmpty(value){
  return (value == null || value.trim().length === 0);
}
```

Comment: `undefined == null` but `undefined !== null`

Comment: @IanBoyd that is because you are comparing == to ===. this means that 
    undefined == null (true)
    undefined != null (false)
    undefined === null (false)
    undefined !== null(true)
would be better to give a bit more information in order to be helpful and push people in the right direction. moz doc on the difference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: value.trim() will crash on theses values : [], {}

Answer (score 73):

This is the safest check and I haven't seen it posted here exactly like that:

```
if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value) {
    //deal with value'
};
```

It will cover cases where **value** was never defined, and also any of these:

- null
- undefined (value of undefined is not the same as a parameter that was never defined)
- 0
- "" (empty string)
- false
- NaN

<sub>Edited: Changed to strict equality (!==) because it's the norm by now ;)</sub>

Comment: I didn't downvote, but with regards to strict equality comparison, the general rule is that unless you _need_ implicit type conversion than strict comparison should be used.

Comment: Thanx for your comment Steve. That general rule is just fine. I just expect for ppl to understand why they use one or the other. Every way you look ppl will be glad to preach you about "always always use strict" - like it's the most important thing in Javascript. 
I've seen too many cases like **if(val !== null)** which obviously lead to an unwanted result.
It's fine to say that when in doubt - use strict, but it's better to not be in doubt.

Comment: I think the point here is that we expect the `typeof` operator to return a string so using the strict equality check is technically more accurate, more specific, and faster. So really, there is no reason to use the loose comparison, not the other way around. Also `val !== null` is perfectly valid in many cases - I do it all the time. I agree with your non-conformity argument, but I think this is a poor example to make it with. Not trying to troll you.

Comment: Thanx for your comment Bryan,
You use val !== null because you know what you’re doing.
A beginner will want to have a fallback to when val is falsy.
But, val will never be null it’ll be undefined. If only he didn’t listen to that advice to “always always use strict” he’ll have less bugs.
I’ve seen this happens in production code.
typeof always returns a string and speed diff will be redundant.
So, the only argument for using strict in the above case is consistency.
I’ve said “No need for strict equality”. It doesn’t mean that you can’t if you want to or if it makes your code more consistent.

Answer (score 36):

A solution I like a lot:

Let's define that a blank variable is `null`, or `undefined`, or if it has length, it is zero, or if it is an object, it has no keys:

```
function isEmpty (value) {
  return (
    // null or undefined
    (value == null) ||

    // has length and it's zero
    (value.hasOwnProperty('length') && value.length === 0) ||

    // is an Object and has no keys
    (value.constructor === Object && Object.keys(value).length === 0)
  )
}
```

Returns:

- **true:** `undefined`, `null`, `""`, `[]`, `{}`
- **false:** `true`, `false`, `1`, `0`, `-1`, `"foo"`, `[1, 2, 3]`, `{ foo: 1 }`

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Finally, it excludes false, and this is what I was looking for. Otherwise the code I was trying to fix was removing the items from array not only on empty values, but also on valid false value, which had to be recorded in the else condition. It was like `if (!value || value === '') { delete a.b[field]; } else { a.b[field] = {val: value, ... }; }` - quite an obvious yet annoying bug ;)

Answer (score 36):

> Take a look at the new ECMAScript [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

You can think of this feature - the `??` operator - as a way to “fall back” to a default value when dealing with `null` or `undefined`.

```js
let x = foo ?? bar();
```

Again, the above code is equivalent to the following.

```js
let x = (foo !== null && foo !== undefined) ? foo : bar();
```

Comment: I didn't realize until this post that nullish coalescing didn't evaluate false on 0 and empty strings, making it infinitely more useful. Thank you!

Comment: I like to use `if ((x ?? null) === null)` to check for `null` or `undefined`

Comment: same idea goes for `??=` . Example: `name ??= 'bob'` is equivalent to `name = (name !== null && name !== undefined) ? name : 'bob'` . [doc: nullish coalescing assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment)

Comment: This is by far the best solution to answer the question if a variable has an assigned value.  However, it isn't a solution for the original question which was if a variable is empty.  They wanted to consider both '' and [] as empty also.

Answer (score 32):

You may find the following function useful:

```
function typeOf(obj) {
  return {}.toString.call(obj).split(' ')[1].slice(0, -1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Or in ES7 (comment if further improvements)

```
function typeOf(obj) {
  const { toString } = Object.prototype;
  const stringified = obj::toString();
  const type = stringified.split(' ')[1].slice(0, -1);

  return type.toLowerCase();
}
```

Results:

```
typeOf(); //undefined
typeOf(null); //null
typeOf(NaN); //number
typeOf(5); //number
typeOf({}); //object
typeOf([]); //array
typeOf(''); //string
typeOf(function () {}); //function
typeOf(/a/) //regexp
typeOf(new Date()) //date
typeOf(new WeakMap()) //weakmap
typeOf(new Map()) //map
```

"Note that the bind operator (::) is not part of ES2016 (ES7) nor any later edition of the ECMAScript standard at all. It's currently a stage 0 (strawman) proposal for being introduced to the language." – Simon Kjellberg. the author wishes to add his support for this beautiful proposal to receive royal ascension.

Comment: +1 it is helpfull to know the object of type  ['regexp'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), 'array' and 'function'

Comment: @Vix, why is the ES7 version any better?

Comment: It isn't, was experimenting with more readable ways of expressing the same functionality making use of: destructuring assignment, bind operator.

Comment: Note that the bind operator (`::`) is not part of ES2016 (ES7) nor any later edition of the ECMAScript standard at all. It's currently a stage 0 (strawman) proposal for being introduced to the language.

Answer (score 30):

This condition check

```
if (!!foo) {
    //foo is defined
}
```

is all you need.

Comment: I assume that this is just a snippet. But `if` already does a falsy check, which this just converts to a Boolean. Does it catch any cases which a normal `if(foo)` does not catch?

Comment: This is perfect for when you need something inline, for example I need a react attribute (called active) that's true when a string isn't empty - an if statement would be overkill so I can just use `active={!!foo}`

Comment: Unless foo is 0

Comment: For more, on MDN see [Double NOT (!!)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT#double_not_!!). Also, if `foo` is `0`, then `!!foo` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Nope!  This is the opposite logic of what the original question asked, a way to test for isEmpty.  This would return true for undefined or null.  But further, this doesn't deal with the fact that 0 and '' are falesy.

Answer (score 28):

The first answer with best rating is wrong. If value is undefined it will throw an exception in modern browsers. You have to use:

```
if (typeof(value) !== "undefined" && value)
```

or

```
if (typeof value  !== "undefined" && value)
```

Comment: eee... I think this is wrong as if(value) is sufficient (except empty objects / arrays). if value is 'undefined' the 'if' confition won't pass.

Comment: This conflates variables which are not defined (which throw a ReferenceError on evaluation), which are different to variables with the `undefined` value.

Comment: I got the same error here. if(x), if(!x), if(!!x) will all throw error if x is undefined.

Comment: `if(value === 0) gameOver();`  ;)

Comment: This answer is also wrong because it returns false when `value` is zero, which is _not_ what op is looking for.

Comment: Read @Qantas94Heavy comment that will clarify the confusion here. We get an exception when referring a variable which is not defined. But here variable is defined and only value is not defined.

Answer (score 22):

## Vacuousness

I don't recommend trying to define or use a function which computes whether any value in the whole world is empty. What does it really mean to be "empty"? If I have `let human = { name: 'bob', stomach: 'empty' }`, should `isEmpty(human)` return `true`? If I have `let reg = new RegExp('');`, should `isEmpty(reg)` return `true`? What about `isEmpty([ null, null, null, null ])` - this list only contains emptiness, so is the list itself empty? I want to put forward here some notes on "vacuousness" (an intentionally obscure word, to avoid pre-existing associations) in javascript - and I want to argue that "vacuousness" in javascript values should never be dealt with generically.

---

### Truthiness/Falsiness

For deciding how to determine the "vacuousness" of values, we need to accomodate javascript's inbuilt, inherent sense of whether values are "truthy" or "falsy". Naturally, `null` and `undefined` are both "falsy". Less naturally, the number `0` (and no other number except `NaN`) is also "falsy". Least naturally: `''` is falsy, but `[]` and `{}` (and `new Set()`, and `new Map()`) are truthy - although they all seem equally vacuous!

---

### Null vs Undefined

There is also some discussion concerning `null` vs `undefined` - do we really need both in order to express vacuousness in our programs? I personally avoid ever having `undefined` appear in my code. I always use `null` to signify "vacuousness". Again, though, we need to accomodate javascript's inherent sense of how `null` and `undefined` differ:

- Trying to access a non-existent property gives `undefined`
- Omitting a parameter when calling a function results in that parameter receiving `undefined`:

```js
let f = a => a;
console.log(f('hi'));
console.log(f());
```

- Parameters with default values receive the default only when given `undefined`, not `null`:

```js
let f = (v='hello') => v;
console.log(f(null));
console.log(f(undefined));
```

To me, `null` is an explicit signifier of vacuousness; "something that could have been filled in was intentionally left blank".

Really `undefined` is a necessary complication that allows some js features to exist, but in my opinion *it should always be left behind the scenes; not interacted with directly*. We can think of `undefined` as, for example, javascript's mechanic for implementing default function arguments. If you refrain from supplying an argument to a function it will receive a value of `undefined` instead. And a default value will be applied to a function argument if that argument was initially set to `undefined`. In this case `undefined` is the linchpin of default function arguments, but it stays in the background: we can achieve default argument functionality without ever referring to `undefined`:

This is a bad implementation of default arguments as it interacts directly with `undefined`:

```
let fnWithDefaults = arg => {
  if (arg === undefined) arg = 'default';
  ...
};
```

This is a good implementation:

```
let fnWithDefaults = (arg='default') => { ... };
```

This is a bad way to accept the default argument:

```
fnWithDefaults(undefined);
```

Simply do this instead:

```
fnWithDefaults();
```

**By the way:** do you have a function with multiple arguments, and you want to provide some arguments while accepting defaults for others?

E.g.:

```
let fnWithDefaults = (a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4) => console.log(a, b, c, d);
```

If you want to provide values for `a` and `d` and accepts defaults for the others what to do? This seems wrong:

```
fnWithDefaults(10, undefined, undefined, 40);
```

The answer is: refactor `fnWithDefaults` to accept a single object:

```
let fnWithDefaults = ({ a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4 }={}) => console.log(a, b, c, d);
fnWithDefaults({ a: 10, d: 40 }); // Now this looks really nice! (And never talks about "undefined")
```

---

### Non-generic Vacuousness

I believe that vacuousness should never be dealt with in a generic fashion. We should instead always have the rigour to get more information about our data before determining if it is vacuous - I mainly do this by checking what type of data I'm dealing with:

```js
let isType = (value, Cls) => {
  // Intentional use of loose comparison operator detects `null`
  // and `undefined`, and nothing else!
  return value != null && Object.getPrototypeOf(value).constructor === Cls;
};
```

Note that this function ignores inheritance - it expects `value` to be a direct instance of `Cls`, and not an instance of a subclass of `Cls`. I avoid `instanceof` for two main reasons:

- `([] instanceof Object) === true`   ("An Array is an Object")
- `('' instanceof String) === false`  ("A String is not a String")

Note that `Object.getPrototypeOf` is used to avoid an (obscure) edge-case such as `let v = { constructor: String };` The `isType` function still returns correctly for `isType(v, String)` (false), and `isType(v, Object)` (true).

Overall, I recommend using this `isType` function along with these tips:

- **Minimize the amount of code processing values of unknown type.** E.g., for `let v = JSON.parse(someRawValue);`, our `v` variable is now of unknown type. As early as possible, we should limit our possibilities. The best way to do this can be by requiring a particular type: e.g. `if (!isType(v, Array)) throw new Error('Expected Array');` - this is a really quick and expressive way to remove the generic nature of `v`, and ensure it's always an `Array`. Sometimes, though, we need to allow `v` to be of multiple types. In those cases, we should create blocks of code where `v` is no longer generic, as early as possible:

```js
if (isType(v, String)) {
  /* v isn't generic in this block - It's a String! */
} else if (isType(v, Number)) {
  /* v isn't generic in this block - It's a Number! */
} else if (isType(v, Array)) {
  /* v isn't generic in this block - it's an Array! */
} else {
  throw new Error('Expected String, Number, or Array');
}
```

- **Always use "whitelists" for validation.** If you require a value to be, e.g., a String, Number, or Array, check for those 3 "white" possibilities, and throw an Error if none of the 3 are satisfied. We should be able to see that checking for "black" possibilities isn't very useful: Say we write `if (v === null) throw new Error('Null value rejected');` - this is great for ensuring that `null` values don't make it through, but if a value *does* make it through, we still know hardly anything about it. A value `v` which passes this null-check is still VERY generic - it's *anything but `null`*! Blacklists hardly dispell generic-ness.
- **Unless a value is `null`, never consider "a vacuous value". Instead, consider "an X which is vacuous".** Essentially, never consider doing anything like `if (isEmpty(val)) { /* ... */ }` - no matter how that `isEmpty` function is implemented (I don't want to know...), it isn't meaningful! And it's way too generic! Vacuousness should only be calculated with knowledge of `val`'s type. Vacuousness-checks should look like this:

  - "A string, with no chars":
    `if (isType(val, String) && val.length === 0) ...`
  - "An Object, with 0 props": `if (isType(val, Object) && Object.entries(val).length === 0) ...`
  - "A number, equal or less than zero": `if (isType(val, Number) && val <= 0) ...`
  - "An Array, with no items": `if (isType(val, Array) && val.length === 0) ...`
  - The only exception is when `null` is used to signify certain functionality. In this case it's meaningful to say: "A vacuous value": `if (val === null) ...`

Answer (score 21):

You are a bit overdoing it. To check if a variable is not given a value, you would only need to check against undefined and null.

```
function isEmpty(value){
    return (typeof value === "undefined" || value === null);
}
```

This is assuming `0`, `""`, and objects(even empty object and array) are valid "values".

Comment: Loose comparison against `null` has always encapsulated this exact behaviour; this function is equivalent to yours: `let isEmpty = val => val == null;`

Answer (score 21):

**!** check for **empty strings (""), null, undefined, false and the number 0 and NaN.** Say, if a string is empty `var name = ""` then `console.log(!name)` returns `true`.

```
function isEmpty(val){
  return !val;
}
```

this function will return true if **val** is **empty, null, undefined, false, the number 0 or NaN**.

**OR**

According to your problem domain you can just use like `!val` or `!!val`.

Comment: This doesn't really say if the variable is empty, since false and 0 can be valid values and not constitute an empty value. The value of having an isEmpty function would be to make sure values you expect that are empty return true.

in my opinion null,undefined, NaN, and an empty string are the values that make sense as empty.

Comment: Why use ``isEmpty(val)`` if you could just do ``!val``?

Comment: It is up to you. You can use it to increase readability. Otherwise if you think the team you work they are more advance coder, then you can use just `!val` or `!!val` according to your problem domain.

Answer (score 14):

The probably shortest answer is

```
val==null || val==''
```

if you change rigth side to `val===''` then empty array will give false. Proof

```js
function isEmpty(val){
    return val==null || val==''
}

// ------------
// TEST
// ------------

var log = (name,val) => console.log(`${name} -> ${isEmpty(val)}`);

log('null', null);
log('undefined', undefined);
log('NaN', NaN);
log('""', "");
log('{}', {});
log('[]', []);
log('[1]', [1]);
log('[0]', [0]);
log('[[]]', [[]]);
log('true', true);
log('false', false);
log('"true"', "true");
log('"false"', "false");
log('Infinity', Infinity);
log('-Infinity', -Infinity);
log('1', 1);
log('0', 0);
log('-1', -1);
log('"1"', "1");
log('"0"', "0");
log('"-1"', "-1");

// "void 0" case
console.log('---\n"true" is:', true);
console.log('"void 0" is:', void 0);
log(void 0,void 0); // "void 0" is "undefined" - so we should get here TRUE
```

More details about `==` (source [here](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/))

[image]

**BONUS**: Reason why `===` is more clear than `==`

[image]

To write clear and  easy 
understandable  code, use explicite list of accepted values

```
val===undefined || val===null || val===''|| (Array.isArray(val) && val.length===0)
```

```js
function isEmpty(val){
    return val===undefined || val===null || val==='' || (Array.isArray(val) && val.length===0)
}

// ------------
// TEST
// ------------

var log = (name,val) => console.log(`${name} -> ${isEmpty(val)}`);

log('null', null);
log('undefined', undefined);
log('NaN', NaN);
log('""', "");
log('{}', {});
log('[]', []);
log('[1]', [1]);
log('[0]', [0]);
log('[[]]', [[]]);
log('true', true);
log('false', false);
log('"true"', "true");
log('"false"', "false");
log('Infinity', Infinity);
log('-Infinity', -Infinity);
log('1', 1);
log('0', 0);
log('-1', -1);
log('"1"', "1");
log('"0"', "0");
log('"-1"', "-1");

// "void 0" case
console.log('---\n"true" is:', true);
console.log('"void 0" is:', void 0);
log(void 0,void 0); // "void 0" is "undefined" - so we should get here TRUE
```

Comment: Helpful visualization! What is the source of them?

Comment: @viam0Zah link to source is below snippet --> `(source here)`

Comment: If typeof val is string assigned with "undefined"?

Answer (score 12):

Here's mine - returns true if value is null, undefined, etc or blank (ie contains only blank spaces):

```
function stringIsEmpty(value) {

    return value ? value.trim().length == 0 : true;

}
```

Comment: I did a test on several methods here. With a check for undefined, your function works great. So I use if(typeof value !== 'undefined' && !IsEmpty(value)) OR, if you actually want to check for empty, you can use if(typeof value === 'undefined' || IsEmpty2(value)). This will work for null; Undefined; 0; ""; " "; false

Answer (score 10):

If you prefer plain javascript try this:

```
  /**
   * Checks if `value` is empty. Arrays, strings, or `arguments` objects with a
   * length of `0` and objects with no own enumerable properties are considered
   * "empty".
   *
   * @static
   * @memberOf _
   * @category Objects
   * @param {Array|Object|string} value The value to inspect.
   * @returns {boolean} Returns `true` if the `value` is empty, else `false`.
   * @example
   *
   * _.isEmpty([1, 2, 3]);
   * // => false
   *
   * _.isEmpty([]);
   * // => true
   *
   * _.isEmpty({});
   * // => true
   *
   * _.isEmpty('');
   * // => true
   */

function isEmpty(value) {
    if (!value) {
      return true;
    }
    if (isArray(value) || isString(value)) {
      return !value.length;
    }
    for (var key in value) {
      if (hasOwnProperty.call(value, key)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Otherwise, if you are already using underscore or lodash, try:

```
_.isEmpty(value)
```

Comment: Have tried your code. I get an error message in the console that says: "Uncaught reference error: isArray() is not defined". Otherwise, would be great if it worked.

Comment: In the case of lodash at least, `_.isNil` is the function you're looking for, not `_.isEmpty`. [isNil documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#isNil), [isEmpty documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#isEmpty)

Comment: This would fail if value is boolean and has the value true.

Comment: Plain javascript doesn't have `isArray` or `isString` functions on the `window`.

Comment: @GFoley83 - You caught me!  I have my reasons for not using Windows.  I actually cover the topic in the chapter that talks about the history and progression of software languages.  More relevant info will likely be the discussion/code demonstrating Monadic Error Handling in my book, Learn Functional Programming in Go.  Cheers!

Comment: @l3x: Is that a joke?

Answer (score 8):

```
return val || 'Handle empty variable'
```

is a really nice and clean way to handle it in a lot of places, can also be used to assign variables

```
const res = val || 'default value'
```

Comment: A lot of places but not when the default is `true` and you're trying to supply or return a `val` of `false`.

Comment: @Molomby that's a very specific edge case but even that is easily handled
`const res = falsyValue ? true :  falsyValue`

Answer (score 7):

If the variable hasn't been declared, you wont be able to test for undefined using a function because you will get an error.

```
if (foo) {}
function (bar) {}(foo)
```

Both will generate an error if foo has not been declared.

If you want to test if a variable has been declared you can use

```
typeof foo != "undefined"
```

if you want to test if foo has been declared and it has a value you can use

```
if (typeof foo != "undefined" && foo) {
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use the nullish coalescing operator `??` to check for `null` and `undefined` values. See the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```js
null ?? 'default string'; // returns "default string"

0 ?? 42;  // returns 0

(null || undefined) ?? "foo"; // returns "foo"
```

Answer (score 6):

*To check Default Value*

```
function typeOfVar (obj) {
      return {}.toString.call(obj).split(' ')[1].slice(0, -1).toLowerCase();
}
function isVariableHaveDefaltVal(variable) {
    if ( typeof(variable) === 'string' ) {  // number, boolean, string, object 
        console.log(' Any data Between single/double Quotes is treated as String ');        
        return (variable.trim().length === 0) ? true : false;
    }else if ( typeof(variable) === 'boolean' ) {
      console.log('boolean value with default value \'false\'');
        return (variable === false) ? true : false;
    }else if ( typeof(variable) === 'undefined' ) {
        console.log('EX: var a; variable is created, but has the default value of undefined.'); 
        return true;
    }else if ( typeof(variable) === 'number' ) { 
        console.log('number : '+variable);
        return (variable === 0 ) ? true : false;
    }else if ( typeof(variable) === 'object' ) {
   //   -----Object-----
        if (typeOfVar(variable) === 'array' && variable.length === 0) {
            console.log('\t Object Array with length = ' + [].length); // Object.keys(variable)
            return true;
        }else if (typeOfVar(variable) === 'string' && variable.length === 0 ) {
            console.log('\t Object String with length = ' + variable.length);
            return true;
        }else if (typeOfVar(variable) === 'boolean' ) {
            console.log('\t Object Boolean = ' + variable);
            return (variable === false) ? true : false;
        }else if (typeOfVar(variable) === 'number' ) {
            console.log('\t Object Number = ' + variable);
            return (variable === 0 ) ? true : false;
        }else if (typeOfVar(variable) === 'regexp' && variable.source.trim().length === 0 ) {
       console.log('\t Object Regular Expression : ');
        return true;
        }else if (variable === null) {
       console.log('\t Object null value');
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
var str = "A Basket For Every Occasion";
str = str.replace(/\s/g, "-");
//The "g" flag in the regex will cause all spaces to get replaced.
```

check Result:

```
isVariableHaveDefaltVal(' '); // string          
isVariableHaveDefaltVal(false); // boolean       
var a;           
isVariableHaveDefaltVal(a);               
isVariableHaveDefaltVal(0); // number             
isVariableHaveDefaltVal(parseInt('')); // NAN isNAN(' '); - true         
isVariableHaveDefaltVal(null);              
isVariableHaveDefaltVal([]);               
isVariableHaveDefaltVal(/ /);              
isVariableHaveDefaltVal(new Object(''));               
isVariableHaveDefaltVal(new Object(false));            
isVariableHaveDefaltVal(new Object(0)); 
typeOfVar( function() {} );
```

I used @Vix function() to check the object of which type.

using instansof «

```
var prototypes_or_Literals = function (obj) {
    switch (typeof(obj)) {
        // object prototypes
        case 'object':
            if (obj instanceof Array)
                return '[object Array]';
            else if (obj instanceof Date)
                return '[object Date]';
            else if (obj instanceof RegExp)
                return '[object regexp]';
            else if (obj instanceof String)
                return '[object String]';
            else if (obj instanceof Number)
                return '[object Number]';

            else
                return 'object';
        // object literals
        default:
            return typeof(obj);
    }   
};
output test «
prototypes_or_Literals( '' ) // "string"
prototypes_or_Literals( new String('') ) // "[object String]"
Object.prototype.toString.call("foo bar") //"[object String]"
```

Comment: [Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

checks 
**==  [Data].  === [Data, Type Of Object]**
JS numbers are always stored as double precision floating point numbers, following the international IEEE 754 standard. 

`// Number Type [int, float literals ]
var int = 77; 
var float = 77.7;
console.log( int.toFixed(10) + '\t' + float.toFixed(10) );
// Object Type
var number = new Number( 77 );
if( int != float ) console.log('Data Not Equal');
if( int == number && int !== number ) console.log('Data is Equal & Types vary');`

Answer (score 6):

It may be usefull.

All values in array represent what you want to be (null, undefined or another things) and you search what you want in it.

```
var variablesWhatILookFor = [null, undefined, ''];
variablesWhatILookFor.indexOf(document.DocumentNumberLabel) > -1
```

Comment: could you explain please. what is going on there

Comment: The array contains some variable that you assumed as empty.

Comment: @JoshKisb all values in array represent what you want to be (null, undefined or another things) and you search what you want in it.

Comment: @ddagsan While JoshKisb may appreciate your reply, you should put your explaination in your answer rather than in the comments

Answer (score 6):

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    if (typeof obj == 'number') return false;
    else if (typeof obj == 'string') return obj.length == 0;
    else if (Array.isArray(obj)) return obj.length == 0;
    else if (typeof obj == 'object') return obj == null || Object.keys(obj).length == 0;
    else if (typeof obj == 'boolean') return false;
    else return !obj;
}
```

In ES6 with trim to handle whitespace strings:

```
const isEmpty = value => {
    if (typeof value === 'number') return false
    else if (typeof value === 'string') return value.trim().length === 0
    else if (Array.isArray(value)) return value.length === 0
    else if (typeof value === 'object') return value == null || Object.keys(value).length === 0
    else if (typeof value === 'boolean') return false
    else return !value
}
```

Comment: great function, thank you! handles every type of value - numbers are left out in all other solutions!

Comment: @FabianvonEllerts Please do not try to edit additional code into someone else's answer. Post it as your own answer, as a comment under the answer, or request in a comment that they update the answer themselves.

Answer (score 5):

**Try With Different Logic**. You can use bellow code for check all four(4) condition for validation like not null, not blank, not undefined and not zero only use this code (!(!(variable))) in javascript and jquery.

```
function myFunction() {
    var data;  //The Values can be like as null, blank, undefined, zero you can test

    if(!(!(data)))
    {
        alert("data "+data);
    } 
    else 
    {
        alert("data is "+data);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the unique and exclusive logic, use and try once. It is different from above logic.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **`TypeScript`** and don't want to account for **"values those are `false`"** then this is the solution for you:

First:   `import { isNullOrUndefined } from 'util';`

Then:    `isNullOrUndefined(this.yourVariableName)`

Please Note: As mentioned [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in/51086731?noredirect=1#comment92168451_51086731) this is now deprecated, use `value === undefined || value === null` instead. [ref](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_isnullorundefined_object).

Comment: I thought this was cool so I initially unvoted, but it's a Node.js thing that's been deprecated. Type definitions file says: `/** @deprecated since v4.0.0 - use "value === null || value === undefined" instead. */`

Comment: Here: https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_isnullorundefined_object. Also: "I thought this was cool so I initially **upvoted**" that should read :)

Comment: Why would the deprecate a useful simple thing like this?  geeeeees.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid getting true if the value is any of the following, according to [jAndy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515349/1934402):

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty string ("")
- 0
- false

One possible solution that might avoid getting truthy values is the following:

```
function isUsable(valueToCheck) {
    if (valueToCheck === 0     || // Avoid returning false if the value is 0.
        valueToCheck === ''    || // Avoid returning false if the value is an empty string.
        valueToCheck === false || // Avoid returning false if the value is false.
        valueToCheck)             // Returns true if it isn't null, undefined, or NaN.
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It would be used as follows:

```
if (isUsable(x)) {
    // It is usable!
}
// Make sure to avoid placing the logical NOT operator before the parameter (isUsable(!x)) and instead, use it before the function, to check the returned value.
if (!isUsable(x)) {
    // It is NOT usable!
}
```

---

In addition to those scenarios, you may want to return false if the **object** or **array** is empty:

- Object: {} (Using [ECMA 7+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Browser_compatibility))
- Array: [] (Using [ECMA 5+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray#Browser_compatibility))

You would go about it this way:

```
function isEmptyObject(valueToCheck) {
    if(typeof valueToCheck === 'object' && !Object.keys(valueToCheck).length){
        // Object is empty!
        return true;
    } else {
        // Object is not empty!
        return false;
    }
}

function isEmptyArray(valueToCheck) {
    if(Array.isArray(valueToCheck) && !valueToCheck.length) {
        // Array is empty!
        return true;
    } else {
        // Array is not empty!
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you wish to check for all whitespace strings (" "), you may do the following:

```
function isAllWhitespace(){
    if (valueToCheck.match(/^ *$/) !== null) {
        // Is all whitespaces!
        return true;
    } else {
        // Is not all whitespaces!
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Note: `hasOwnProperty` returns true for empty strings, 0, false, NaN, null, and undefined, if the variable was declared as any of them, so it might not be the best to use. The function may be modified to use it to show that it was declared, but is not usable.

Answer (score 4):

The optional chaining operator provides a way to simplify accessing values through connected objects when it's possible that a reference or function may be undefined or null.

```
let customer = {
  name: "Carl",
  details: {
    age: 82,
    location: "Paradise Falls" // detailed address is unknown
  }
};
let customerCity = customer.details?.address?.city;
```

The nullish coalescing operator may be used after optional chaining in order to build a default value when none was found:

```
let customer = {
  name: "Carl",
  details: { age: 82 }
};
const customerCity = customer?.city ?? "Unknown city";
console.log(customerCity); // Unknown city
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function isEmpty(val){
    return !val;
}
```

but this solution is over-engineered, if you dont'want to modify the function later for busines-model needings, then is cleaner to use it directly in code:

```
if(!val)...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var myNewValue = myObject && myObject.child && myObject.child.myValue;
```

This will never throw an error. If *myObject*, *child*, or *myValue* is null then *myNewValue* will be null. No errors will be thrown

Answer (score 3):

For everyone coming here for having similar question, the following works great and I have it in my library the last years:

```
(function(g3, $, window, document, undefined){
   g3.utils = g3.utils || {};
/********************************Function type()********************************
* Returns a lowercase string representation of an object's constructor.
* @module {g3.utils}
* @function {g3.utils.type}
* @public
* @param {Type} 'obj' is any type native, host or custom.
* @return {String} Returns a lowercase string representing the object's 
* constructor which is different from word 'object' if they are not custom.
* @reference http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215046/differentiating-between-arrays-and-hashes-in-javascript
* http://javascript.info/tutorial/type-detection
*******************************************************************************/
g3.utils.type = function (obj){
   if(obj === null)
      return 'null';
   else if(typeof obj === 'undefined')
      return 'undefined';
   return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).match(/^\[object\s(.*)\]$/)[1].toLowerCase();
};
}(window.g3 = window.g3 || {}, jQuery, window, document));
```

Answer (score 3):

[Code on GitHub](https://github.com/ppo/gist/tree/master/javascript/is-utils)

```js
const isEmpty = value => (
  (!value && value !== 0 && value !== false)
  || (Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 0)
  || (isObject(value) && Object.keys(value).length === 0)
  || (typeof value.size === 'number' && value.size === 0)

  // `WeekMap.length` is supposed to exist!?
  || (typeof value.length === 'number'
      && typeof value !== 'function' && value.length === 0)
);

// Source: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/javascript-check-if-a-variable-is-an-object-and-nothing-else-not-an-array-a-set-etc-a3987ea08fd7
const isObject = value =>
  Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Object]';
```

**Poor man's tests**

```js
const test = () => {
  const run = (label, values, expected) => {
    const length = values.length;
    console.group(`${label} (${length} tests)`);
    values.map((v, i) => {
      console.assert(isEmpty(v) === expected, `${i}: ${v}`);
    });
    console.groupEnd();
  };

  const empty = [
    null, undefined, NaN, '', {}, [],
    new Set(), new Set([]), new Map(), new Map([]),
  ];
  const notEmpty = [
    ' ', 'a', 0, 1, -1, false, true, {a: 1}, [0],
    new Set([0]), new Map([['a', 1]]),
    new WeakMap().set({}, 1),
    new Date(), /a/, new RegExp(), () => {},
  ];
  const shouldBeEmpty = [
    {undefined: undefined}, new Map([[]]),
  ];

  run('EMPTY', empty, true);
  run('NOT EMPTY', notEmpty, false);
  run('SHOULD BE EMPTY', shouldBeEmpty, true);
};
```

**Test results:**

```
EMPTY (10 tests)
NOT EMPTY (16 tests)
SHOULD BE EMPTY (2 tests)
  Assertion failed: 0: [object Object]
  Assertion failed: 1: [object Map]
```

Comment: great function, all of the other answers here had multiple issues which yours appears to address, I just wish I'd found it before I'd written my own :p thought you might like to take a look at my work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in/61350550#61350550 both of our functions appear to have exactly the same output but I've cut down on code a little. Please let me know if I've missed anything.

Comment:  Did you try my "Poor man's tests"? I think I ended up adding more tests in the function for special cases like Map, WeakMap, and maybe also Date, RegExp.
Are you sure about your `value.constructor === Object`? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8511350/101831).

Comment: Yes, I did run your tests, thanks for those, both of our functions return the same results with both of our tests. I keep wondering if I'm missing something outside of these test cases. I believe `value.constructor === Object` is okay, in javascript IF OR statements have execution order so that OR statement will only execute if the previous didn't return TRUE and we've already checked for `Null`. In fact the only purpose of that last OR statement is to detect `{}` and ensure it doesn't return TRUE for things it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

```
function notEmpty(value){
  return (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value.trim().length);
}
```

it will also check white spaces ('    ') along with following:

- null ,undefined ,NaN ,empty ,string ("") ,0 ,false

Answer (score 2):

Will return `false` only for `undefined` and `null`:

`return value ?? false`

Comment: Not exactly: `false ?? false === false`

Comment: Yeah, this suggestion will return `false` for the `false` input as well...

Comment: To be clear, this answer is *incorrect* in that , `!(0 ?? false) === true`

Answer (score 2):

this is my solution to check if data is empty or not.

```
const _isEmpty = (data) => {
  return (
    // this way we can also check for undefined values. null==undefined is true
    data == null ||
    data == "" ||
    (Array.isArray(data) && data.length === 0) ||
    // we want {} to be false. we cannot use !! because !!{} turns to be true
    // !!{}=true and !!{name:"yilmaz"}=true. !! does not work ofr objects
    (data.constructor === Object && Object.keys(data).length === 0)

  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Check for undefined and null ONLY using "nullish coalescing"

```
if ((myVariable ?? undefined) !== undefined) {
    // handle myVariable has a value, including 0 or ""
}
else {
    // handle undefined or null only
}
```

from chrome console

```
{const x=undefined; (x ?? undefined) !== undefined}
false

{const x=null; (x ?? undefined) !== undefined}
false

{const x=0; (x ?? undefined) !== undefined}
true

{const x=""; (x ?? undefined) !== undefined}
true

{const x={}; (x ?? undefined) !== undefined}
true

{const x=[]; (x ?? undefined) !== undefined}
true

{const x="a"; (x ?? undefined) !== undefined}
true
```

Answer (score 1):

This will check if variable of indeterminate nesting is undefined

```
function Undef(str) 
{
  var ary = str.split('.');
  var w = window;
  for (i in ary) {
    try      { if (typeof(w = w[ary[i]]) === "undefined") return true; }
    catch(e) { return true; }
  }
  return false;
}

if (!Undef("google.translate.TranslateElement")) {
```

The above checks if the Google translate function TranslateElement exists.  This is equivalent to:

```
if (!(typeof google === "undefined" 
 || typeof google.translate === "undefined" 
 || typeof google.translate.TranslateElement === "undefined")) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the existing answers failed for my use case, most returned empty if a function was assigned to the variable or if NaN was returned. Pascal's answer was good.

Here's my implementation, please test and let me know if you find anything. You can see how I tested this function [here](https://gist.github.com/SeanBannister/e80882d89f104a0b46020e310640ca4f).

```
function isEmpty(value) {
  return (
    // Null or undefined.
    (value == null) ||
    // Check if a Set() or Map() is empty
    (value.size === 0) ||
    // NaN - The only JavaScript value that is unequal to itself.
    (value !== value) ||
    // Length is zero && it's not a function.
    (value.length === 0 && typeof value !== "function") ||
    // Is an Object && has no keys.
    (value.constructor === Object && Object.keys(value).length === 0)
  )
}
```

Returns:

- **true:** `undefined`, `null`, `""`, `[]`, `{}`, `NaN`, `new Set()`, `//`
- **false:** `true`, `false`, `1`, `0`, `-1`, `"foo"`, `[1, 2, 3]`, `{ foo: 1 }`, `function () {}`

Answer (score 1):

Try [Boolean()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) and [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) (for number type) to check a variable has a value or not.

```js
function isEmpty(val) {
  return typeof val === 'number' ? isNaN(val) : !Boolean(val);
}

var emptyVals = [undefined, null, false, NaN, ''];
emptyVals.forEach(v => console.log(isEmpty(v)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this makes your code looks simpler

To check if variable IS `undefined` or `null`

```
var a=undefined, b=null, c='hello world', d;
if(a !== (a ?? {})) { /**/ } // true
if(b !== (b ?? {})) { /**/ } // true
if(c !== (c ?? {})) { /**/ } // false
if(d !== (d ?? {})) { /**/ } // true
```

To check if variable is NOT `undefined` or `null`

```
var a=undefined, b=null, c='hello world', d;
if(a === (a ?? {})) { /**/ } // false
if(b === (b ?? {})) { /**/ } // false
if(c === (c ?? {})) { /**/ } // true
if(d === (d ?? {})) { /**/ } // false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using the ? operator is slightly cleaner.

```
var ? function_if_exists() : function_if_doesnt_exist();
```

Answer (score 0):

Although an oldie, what forget is that they should wrap their code block and then catch the error and then test...

```
function checkup( t ){
  try{
    for(p in t){
      if( p.hasOwnProperty( t ) ){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }catch(e){
    console.log("ERROR : "+e);
    return e;
  }
}
```

So you really don't have to check for a potential problem before hand, you simply catch it and then deal with it how you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the equality operator

```
<script>
    var firstName;
    var lastName = null;
    /* Since null == undefined is true, the following statements will catch both null and undefined */
        if(firstName == null){
            alert('Variable "firstName" is undefined.');
        }    
        if(lastName == null){
           alert('Variable "lastName" is null.');
        }
</script>
```

demo @ [How to determine if variable is undefined or null using JavaScript](http://www.jquerypot.com/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null-using-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

```
try{

     let vari = obj.propTest; // obj may be don't have propTest property

        ...
} catch(NullException){
    // do something here
}
```

I think using try catch will avoid any error of null check, also in Angular or JavaScript
Just catching null exception and process in it.

Comment: It might be even more helpful to include an explanation of what your code does, and why it answers the question. Posting just code can sometimes be unclear.

Comment: You should add an explanation to justify your answer.

Comment: I tried to code in Angular with some solutions in this question, but I saw that try catch is safe way to process in this case :D

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me. Please do a slight change to make this fast

```js
function isEmpty(obj) {
    if (!obj) return true;
    if (typeof obj == 'number') return false;
    else if (typeof obj == 'string') return obj.length == 0;
    else if (Array.isArray(obj)) return obj.length == 0;
    else if (typeof obj == 'object') return obj == null || Object.keys(obj).length == 0;
    else if (typeof obj == 'boolean') return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This function check for `empty object {}`,`empty array []`, `null`, `undefined` and `blank string ""`

```
function isEmpty(val) {
  //check for empty object {}, array []
  if (val !== null && typeof val === 'object') {
    if (Object.keys(obj).length === 0) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  //check for undefined, null and "" 
  else if (val == null || val === "") {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

> var val={};
>    isEmpty(val) ->   true
>   val=[];
>   isEmpty(val) ->   true
>   isEmpty(undefined) -> true
>   isEmpty(null) -> true
>   isEmpty("") -> true
>   isEmpty(false) -> false
>   isEmpty(0) -> false

Answer (score -1):

This covers empty Array and empty Object also

> null, undefined, ' ', 0, [ ], { }

```
isEmpty = (value) => (!value  || (typeof v === 'object' &&
   Object.keys(value).length < 1));
```

Answer (score -1):

1. you can use the arguments
2. become arguments to array
3. filter

```js
function validateAttrs(arg1, arg2, arg3,arg4){
    var args = Object.values(arguments);
    return (args.filter(x=> x===null || !x)).length<=0
}
console.log(validateAttrs('1',2, 3, 4));
console.log(validateAttrs('1',2, 3, null));
console.log(validateAttrs('1',undefined, 3, 4));
console.log(validateAttrs('1',2, '', 4));
console.log(validateAttrs('1',2, 3, null));
```

Answer (score -2):

For my case I tried with if null,'', !variable, But it did not work.

See my code below to get the text from an html field

```
var status=$(this).text(); //for example (for my case)
```

if there was no value(no text) in the status variable ,I was trying to set the value 'novalue' to status variable.

the following code worked.

```
if(status == false)
{
   status='novalue';
}
```

when there was no text found for satus variable the above code assigned 'novalue' to the status variable

Comment: would really like to know why this is getting downvotes? it would be really helpful. If you are downvoting please explain why you think this answer is wrong.

Comment: I think its not reallly answering the question. You explain a problem that you had, but there was already a good solution to the question by somebody else years before you answered it.

Answer (score -4):

you can always use [loadash](https://lodash.com) functions, like [_.isNil](https://lodash.com/docs#isNil) or [_.isUndefined](https://lodash.com/docs#isUndefined). They are pretty easy to use.

Comment: your answer is not useful as it provides no documentation links towards the functions you mention.