# Easiest way to check if string is null or empty

Tags: coffeescript

I've got this code that checks for the empty or null string. It's working in testing.

```
eitherStringEmpty= (email, password) ->
  emailEmpty = not email? or email is ''
  passwordEmpty = not password? or password is ''
  eitherEmpty = emailEmpty || passwordEmpty         

test1 = eitherStringEmpty "A", "B" # expect false
test2 = eitherStringEmpty "", "b" # expect true
test3 = eitherStringEmpty "", "" # expect true
alert "test1: #{test1} test2: #{test2} test3: #{test3}"
```

What I'm wondering is if there's a better way than `not email? or email is ''`. Can I do the equivalent of C# `string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg)` in CoffeeScript with a single call? I could always define a function for it (like I did) but I'm wondering if there's something in the language that I'm missing.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Yup:

```
passwordNotEmpty = not not password
```

or shorter:

```
passwordNotEmpty = !!password
```

Comment: This is the more "javascript-y" of the two answers.  Particularly if you use the `!!` version, which is a common way to essentially cast to boolean.  If it matters, this is almost certainly faster than defining a function as Jeremy suggested.

Comment: They all work, but this one got the most upvotes. I like http://stackoverflow.com/q/8127920/30946 for readability tho.

Comment: It fails for string with all spaces...so doesn't work for blank

Comment: @Arkhitech blank is not the same thing as empty, so it works.

Comment: Too "clever" for my taste in readability; don't think I'll use it, but good work though

Comment: Cool, JS goes the way of Python. Readability and Efficience Boost Squared.

Answer (score 38):

It isn't entirely equivalent, but `email?.length` will only be truthy if `email` is non-null and has a non-zero `.length` property. If you `not` this value the result should behave as you want for both strings and arrays.

If `email` is `null` or doesn't have a `.length`, then `email?.length` will evaluate to `null`, which is falsey. If it does have a `.length` then this value will evaluate to its length, which will be falsey if it's empty.

Your function could be implemented as:

```
eitherStringEmpty = (email, password) ->
  not (email?.length and password?.length)
```

Comment: @pyrotechnick The question didn't ask about distinguishing Arrays from Strings. It asked about distinguishing null values and empty strings from non-empty strings. My point was that the code could also distinguish null values and empty arrays from non-empty arrays, but that was beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Nevertheless, "eitherStringEmpty" is an incorrect name for the method you provided.

Answer (score 14):

This is a case where "truthiness" comes in handy. You don't even need to define a function for that:

```
test1 = not (email and password)
```

Why does it work?

```
'0'       // true
'123abc'  // true
''        // false
null      // false
undefined // false
```

Comment: I assume you have already called `.trim()` on the value as part of your validation logic. The answer is more about CS syntax.

Answer (score 5):

```
unless email? and email
  console.log 'email is undefined, null or ""'
```

First check if email is not undefined and not null with the existential operator, then if you know it exists the `and email` part will only return false if the email string is empty.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the coffeescript or= operation

```
s = ''    
s or= null
```

Comment: Wow, that is amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check that the content is a string, not null and not an array, use a simple typeof comparison:

```
 if typeof email isnt "string"
```

Comment: `typeof email isnt "string"` returns false for both `''` and `'a'`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xd7qY/12/) demonstrating a very easy way of doing this.

Basicly you simply do this is javascript:

```
var email="oranste";
var password="i";

if(!(email && password)){
    alert("One or both not set");        
}
else{
    alert("Both set");   
}
```

In coffescript:

```
email = "oranste"
password = "i"
unless email and password
  alert "One or both not set"
else
  alert "Both set"
```

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the question mark is the easiest way to call a function on a thing if the thing exists.

for example

```
car = {
  tires: 4,
  color: 'blue' 
}
```

you want to get the color, but only if the car exists...

coffeescript:

```
 car?.color
```

translates to javascript:

```
if (car != null) {
  car.color;
}
```

it is called the existential operator http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/grammar.html#section-63

Comment: Empty string returns true for existence check.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure @thejh 's answer was good enough to check empty string BUT,
I think we frequently need to check that 'Does it exist?' and then we need to check 'Is it empty? include string, array and object'

This is the shorten way for CoffeeScript to do this.

```
tmp? and !!tmp and !!Object.keys(tmp).length
```

If we keep this question order, that would be checked by this order
  1. does it exist?
  2. not empty string?
  3. not empty object?

so there wasn't any problems for all variable even in the case of not existed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515349/905801) about checking if a variable has a `truthy` value or not , you just need one line:

```
result = !email or !password
```

& you can try it for yourself on this [online Coffeescript console](http://larryng.github.io/coffeescript-repl/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the accepted answer `passwordNotEmpty = !!password` you can use

```
passwordNotEmpty = if password then true else false
```

It gives the same result (the difference only in syntax).

In the first column is a value, in the second is the result of `if value`:

```
0 - false
5 - true
'string' - true
'' - false
[1, 2, 3] - true
[] - true
true - true
false - false
null - false
undefined - false
```