# whats the best method to test for truthiness in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

Is it acceptable to just test for "truthy" in coffeescript? I'm looking for a best practice to soak up empty strings in object attributes.

Given:

```
obj = {
  "isNull": null,
  "isEmptyString": "",
  "isZero": 0
}

## coffeescript
# obj.isNull?         === true
# obj.isEmptyString?  === false
# obj.isZero?         === false
```

Which is safer or preferable??

```
# obj.isEmptyString    ==  "truthy"    
# !!obj.isEmptyString  === true
```

Comment: Why make any difference to regular Javascript? `obj.isNull`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `!!` is the accepted method:

```
obj = {"isNull": null, "isEmptyString": "", "isZero": 0, "isValue": 1}
!!obj.isNull # false
!!obj.isEmptyString # false
!!obj.isZero # false
!!obj.isValue # true
```

EDIT: Possible duplicate: [Easiest way to check if string is null or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127883/easiest-way-to-check-if-string-is-null-or-empty)