# How do I check for undefined types in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

What is the best way to check for the `undefined` type in JavaScript? I know one way to check is by using `typeOf`, but I have to check for it in lots of places; is there a shorter or better way to do this?

I tried a few ways but didn't succeed:

```
alert(undefined === "undefined");
alert(undefined || "defined");
```

Comment: Put the vanilla `typeof foo === "undefined"` in to a `isDefined(value, [default])` function

Comment: You already know the best way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing new for you:

```
// either
(val === undefined)
// or
(typeof val == "undefined")
```

The problem of using `val || "defined"` is that "defined" will be returned in case `val` is `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `false` or `""`.

Answer (score 1):

That is the best way what you said using typeof.

Example:

```
alert(typeof variable === 'undefined')
```

Comment: `typeof` always returns string, so there is no special need for `===`.

Comment: Yes, no special needs but I am in safe with that. I want to compare strictly the strings, no more conversion, I know that `typeof` returns string.

Comment: @VisioN `===` is marginally faster than `==`, so it is actually preferred.

Comment: @JanDvorak I've made a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/2eq-vs-3eq) to check. My results are different each new test run (Chrome 22).

Comment: @VisioN It looks equal to within statistical error. Thanks

Comment: @VisioN it's better to pretend `==` doesn't exist.

Comment: @jbabey—given javascript's loose typing, `==` is very handy, e.g. `1 == '1'`. Imagine having to cast everything to the same Type before doing comparisons (which is more-or-less what `==` does anyway). I prefer to only use `===` where necessary and use `==` everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Using `typeof val == "undefined"` is the best way since the value of `undefined` can be modified.

```
var x;

console.log("x == undefined => " + (x == undefined));
console.log("typeof x == 'undefined' => " + (typeof x == 'undefined'));

var undefined = 10; // for some reason, browsers allow this!
console.log('undefined overwritten to ' + undefined);

console.log("x == undefined => " + (x == undefined)); // this will return false!
console.log("typeof x == 'undefined' => " + (typeof x == 'undefined'));
```

Comment: In ES5, the [`undefined`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.3) property of the global object is read only, so you can't set its value to anything else.

Answer (score -1):

```
var variable2 = variable1  || '';
```

If Variable 1 is undefined, it'll set it to '', else, it'll use variable1.

Comment: More accurately "If Variable1 is *falsey* ..."