# How to redirect on another page and pass parameter in url from table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, jquery-mobile, tornado

How to redirect on another page and pass parameter in url from table ?
I've created in tornato template something like this

```
<table data-role="table" id="my-table" data-mode="reflow">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Nation</th>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for result  in players %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{result['username']}}</td>
            <td>{{result['nation']}}</td>
            <td>{{result['rank']}}</td>
            <td><input type="button" name="theButton" value="Detail"
                       ></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    {% end %}
</table>
```

and I would like when I press detail to be redirect on `/player_detail?username=username`
and show all detail about that player.
I tried with `href="javascript:window.location.replace('./player_info');"` inside input tag but don't know how to put result['username'] in.
 How to do this ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Set the user name as `data-username` attribute to the button and also a class:

*HTML*

```
<input type="button" name="theButton" value="Detail" class="btn" data-username="{{result['username']}}" />
```

*JS*

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {

    var name = $(this).data('username');        
    if (name != undefined && name != null) {
        window.location = '/player_detail?username=' + name;
    }
});​
```

**EDIT:**

Also, you can simply check for `undefined` && `null` using:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {

    var name = $(this).data('username');        
    if (name) {
        window.location = '/player_detail?username=' + name;
    }
});​
```

As, mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515349/1823841)

```
if (name) {            
}
```

will evaluate to true if value is not:

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty string ("")
- 0
- false

The above list represents all possible falsy values in ECMA/Javascript.

Comment: there's a little error: the "(" before function should't be there.

Comment: shouldn't the check against the name var be a &&, instead of a ||?

Comment: One question, if I want to pass 3 parameters to build in the other url n img I'll have to do the same as your answer?

Answer (score 8):

Do this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDetails(username)
{
   window.location = '/player_detail?username='+username;
}
</script>

<input type="button" name="theButton" value="Detail" onclick="showDetails('username');">
```

Answer (score 7):

Bind the button, this is done with jQuery:

```
$("#my-table input[type='button']").click(function(){
    var parameter = $(this).val();
    window.location = "http://yoursite.com/page?variable=" + parameter;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a general solution that doesn't rely on JQuery. Simply modify the definition of window.location.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         function loadNewDoc(){ 
            var loc = window.location;
            window.location = loc.hostname + loc.port + loc.pathname + loc.search; 
         };
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onLoad="loadNewDoc()">
   </body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML - set an id attribute

```
<input type="button" id="go-another-page" name="theButton" value="Detail">Go to another page with parameters</td>
```

JS - Create an action listener for redirecting

```
  const anotherPackage = document.getElementById('go-another-page');

   anotherPackage.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
   // After ? mark set your key and variable eg: payment=order-consulting
   // For multiple parameters you can use & eg: payment=order-consulting&amount=20
    window.location.replace('/payment.html?payment=order-consulting');
  });
```

Retrieve parameters from another page (In this case, payment.html)

```
// payment.js - this is javascript of your another page
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const parameters = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const payment = parameters.get('payment');
  console.log(payment);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```