# Pass an array as url parameter and redirect to new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, redirect

I want to pass an array as url GET parameter and redirect to new page. I don't know how to pass an array with `window.location.href`. Is there any way in Ajax to redirect to new page with array as parameter(with or without `window.location.href`) or is there any other function for redirecting to other page in which I can pass an array as parameter from the front-end.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14101120/4248328

Comment: You can store your aaray to localstorage and then when you land on the page where you want to redirect, you can read that localStorage .

Comment: But the above link doesn't show how to pass an array as GET parameter. @AlivetoDie

Comment: you can't pass array as a parameter. you can pass query-string

Comment: Okay @AlivetoDie

Answer (score 7, accepted):

with jQuery [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) function you can convert array to http query

```
var data = {myArr: [1,2,3,4,5]};
console.log("index.php?" + $.param(data));    
// index.php?myArr%5B%5D=1&myArr%5B%5D=2&myArr%5B%5D=3&myArr%5B%5D=4&myArr%5B%5D=5
```

Comment: Does my job.@Peter

Comment: @UtkarshGarg  it's not an array parameter passing.it's called query-string

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 info[0] = 'hi';
 info[1] = 'hello';
 info = JSON.stringify(info);

           $.ajax({
                url: "index.php?info="+info,
                data: data_to_send,
                success: function(msg){
                    $('.answer').html(msg);
                }
            });
```

In backend code just json_decode the **info** and use.