# how to redirect to another page while passing an attribute to the other page?

Tags: javascript

This is the code written on current page,i have to pass attributes from this page to the other page:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("buttons").click(function() {
            $(location).attr('href', 'www.google.co.in');
         });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: www.test.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5  use this

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query string (**https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string**) like this:

`http://example.com/path/to/page?firstParameter=data1&secondParameter=data2`

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate(I believe). Check out this link. It clearly highlights how values can be passed from one page to another. 
[How to redirect on another page and pass parameter in url from table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100563/how-to-redirect-on-another-page-and-pass-parameter-in-url-from-table)