# Why is this angular js todo app only checking an if statement once?

Tags: angularjs

In the function $scope.addTodo(), my browser is only evaluating the if statement upon the first entry onto the $scope.todos array. After I create a single todo, I can now push blank todos, even though that is not the desired outcome. What is strange too, is that if I change the if statement from

```js
if ($scope.formTodoText != null)
```

to

```js
if ($scope.formTodoText != "")
```

then I can submit a blank todo, but only once. After that initial blank todo is submitted, there are no problems with the evaluation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style type="text/css">
  .done-true {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: grey;
  }
</style> 

</head>
<body>

  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl" class="container">

    <h2>Total Todos: {{getTotalTodos()}}</h2>
    <ul class="unstyled">
      <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done"> 
        <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <input type="text" ng-model="formTodoText" ng-model-instant>
      <button class="btn" ng-click="addTodo()"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Add</button>
    </form>
    <button class="btn-large" ng-click="clearCompleted()"> <i class="icon-trash"></i> Clear</button>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function TodoCtrl($scope) {


      $scope.todos = [
        {text: 'Learn angular', done: false},
        {text: 'Build an app', done: false},
        {text: 'Design UI', done: false}
      ];

      $scope.getTotalTodos = function() {
        return $scope.totalTodos = $scope.todos.length;
      };

      $scope.clearCompleted = function () {
        $scope.todos = _.filter($scope.todos, function (todo) {
            return !todo.done;
        });
      };

      $scope.addTodo = function() {
        if ($scope.formTodoText != null) {
            $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.formTodoText, done: false});
            $scope.formTodoText = "";
        }
      };
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where does `ng-model-instant` come from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should use the `!==` and `===` operators (instead of the `!=` and `==` operators) for comparison in JavaScript.

You might also find `console.log` handy for this. Try adding

```
    console.log($scope.formTodoText);
```

as the first line of the `$scope.addTodo` function body to see what it contains.

For the first case, where you used:

```
    if ($scope.formTodoText != null) {
```

Initially, we cannot submit empty todo (without doing some kind of editing on the input field) because `$scope.formTodoText` is `undefined`. This causes the `if ($scope.formTodoText != null)` check to fail, so it does not get added. However, if you type some characters into the input field and then erase them, you will find that it is still possible to add empty todos, since `$scope.formTodoText` will become the empty string and `'' != null`, so we enter the `if` body and add the empty todo.

Now, suppose we create a single, non empty todo. This calls the `$scope.addTodo` function. Since `$scope.formTodoText` is not null, this pushes the todo onto the list. Then, it resets `$scope.formTodoText` to the empty string. This is the reason why we were able to add empty todos from here on without editing the contents of the input field, because `$scope.formTodoText` is set to the empty string and `'' != null`

If instead, we use:

```
    if ($scope.formTodoText != '') {
```

and then click the add button (without doing anything to the input field prior to that), then `$scope.formTodoText` will be `undefined`, and `undefined != ''`, so we go into the body of the `if` statement. This is followed by a push of `{text: undefined, done: false}` into `$scope.todos`. After that, `$scope.formTodoText` is set to the empty string, and adding todos which are the empty string fails from this point on.

To prevent empty todos, one way is to change the condition to:

```
    if ($scope.formTodoText) {
```

so `$scope.formTodoText` will check that `$scope.formTodoText` is a "truthy" value, which automatically excludes "falsy" values, in particular `undefined` and the empty string. For more information on truthy and falsy values, see http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/javascript-conventions/what-are-truthy-and-falsy-values