# How can I loop through an array object and check each element to see if one is defined?

Tags: javascript

I have an array object that looks like this:

```
var myArr = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined];
```

How can I loop through the array object and call a function if any one of
the elements in the array is defined and not null?

Comment: Do you mean "defined" in the sense of the Array member exists, or "defined" in the sense of "exists, and not `undefined`"? You also then say "not null", so are you saying you also want a `null` check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care what the valid value is:

```
var myFunction = function(){console.log("array has valid values");};
var myArr = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 2];
var hasUndefined = myArr.some(function(item){
    return typeof item !== "undefined";
});
if (hasUndefined){
    myFunction();
}
```

If you need to find out what the valid items are:

```
var myFunction = function(validItems){
    console.log("array has valid values, and here they are:",validItems);
};
var myArr = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 2];
var validItems = myArr.filter(function(item){return typeof item !== "undefined";})
if (validItems.length){
    myFunction(validItems);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArr = [null,undefined,4,5];

for (var i in myArr) {
    if (myArr[i]) {
        //Do something..
        return;
    }
}
```

I've also seen this which seems a very nice way.

```
[null,undefined,4,5].every(function(e) {
    if (e) {
        //Do something..
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
});
```

[Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

Comment: He wants to avoid null as well and `forEach` will make the function to be executed for every valid element.

Comment: You are right I think I misinterpret what he want. But I think `!==` avoids null although I must check.

Comment: Even `return` will not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function isNotUndefined(item) {
    return typeof item != "undefined";
}

if (myArr.some(isNotUndefined)) {
   //do something
}
```

In this code I use the `Array.prototype.some` function to check if any element is defined (to do this I use an extra function called `isNotUndefined`).

Comment: Doesn't work for me, although it seems a very nice way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var myArr = [undefined, null, 123, undefined, null, 456];//for test
myArrFilterd = myArr.filter(function(x){return x!=null?true:false;});
myArrFilterd.forEach(function(x){console.log(x);/*something you want to do for each element*/});
```

output:

```
123
456
```