# Testing for variables existence not working as expected in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've watched several Doug Crockford videos about the "right" way to do JavaScript and I've tried to follow his suggestions.  Currently in our system we do lot of

```
if (myvar != null) {
   //do some stuff
}
```

However, I understand this only works because of type coercion and that myvar is actually undefined until it is initialized.

I have a common block of code in which I've added some new stuff that I only want executed one one page.  In that one page's JavaScript I've put a new variable ala:

```
var doingStuffTheNewWay = true;
```

In my common block of code I have a test like:

```
if (doingStuffTheNewWay && someOtherCondition) {
   // new code
} else {
   // old code
}
```

However, it's blowing up on evaluating doingStuffTheNewWay and not going into my else case.  I thought it would evaluate doingStuffTheNewWay  as a falsie value, if it didn't know what it was ala [Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in).  Any suggestions for how to handle this?

Comment: _"it's blowing up on evaluating `doingStuffTheNewWay`"_? With _"Blowing up"_, do you mean it's throwing errors? If so, what errors? If your PC is literally exploding, you might want to remove that line of code.

Comment: The accepted answer in the question you linked contains the solution (`typeof`).

Comment: My computer is literally exploded, which is why it's so important to fix this bug....

Comment: @Eric If you actually describe the error that's being thrown, or what happens specifically, you'll get help much faster.

Comment: @Eric, joking aside, I was seriously asking for the error code you're getting...