# Does (!value) Evaluate as True for All Falsy Values?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, boolean

I understand that

```
if( value ) {
```

}

will evaluate to true if value IS NOT null, undefined, NaN, empty string (""), 0, or false

But, does 
`if (! value ) {}`
evaluate to true if the value IS null, undefined, NaN, empty string (""), 0, or false ?

I am using Google Scripts and I am taking data from a spreadsheet in which some cells are blank. For those cells I want to be sure the value returns as "empty string" rather than any of the other possibilities like, undefined, for example (some are currently returning 'undefined' which is what led me to seek this answer).

I would like to use this code, as long as it does what I think it does:

```
if (! value ) {value = ""}
```

(P.S. I started at this thread: [Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in), but the answers do not address the opposite scenario)

Answer (score 1):

In short, **yes**.

Coerce or cast the value to boolean by using the negative `!` and double negative `!!` which will turn all falsey values to `false` and all other values to `true`, then just check wether its true or false knowing they're boolean.

So, in other words, if you want the boolean of the opposite, just prepend `!` if you want the boolean of the actual value, prepend `!!`

```
 !"" === true; //inverted
!!"" === false;//actual
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those will evaluate to true:

```
if(!NaN){console.log('true!');}
true!
if(!undefined){console.log('true!');}
true!
if(!null){console.log('true!');}
true!
if(!''){console.log('true!');}
true!
if(!0){console.log('true!');}
true!
```