# Does a truthy value in JavaScript always have a hasOwnProperty method?

Tags: javascript

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515349) we can see which types of objects in JavaScript/ECMAScript evaluate to `false`.

**My question is: if a variable evaluates to `true`, is it guaranteed to have a `hasOwnProperty` method?**

In other words, is the following test safe?

```
if (bar && bar.hasOwnProperty("foo")) { ... }
```

My goal is to prevent exceptions like `Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null`.

My application scenario: in an AngularJS `$http` service error handler I want to be prepared for all situations. This is a little difficult for me, because I am not tremendously experienced with JavaScript and the different situations in which this error handler might be called can not easily be tested for. The error handler function has the following signature:

```
function(data, status, headers, config) {}
```

In the function body I evaluate `data` like so:

```
if (data && data.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
    alert(data.error);
}
```

Does this look safe to you under all circumstances? Safe in the sense that this test does not throw an exception, no matter how AngularJS actually calls the error handler.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null` since `null` is falsey, this shouldn't be a problem. @DenysSéguret: If you are dealing with a variable, this should be okay. For example `var a = 1;` then `a.hasOwnProperty` is a function.

Comment: @DenysSéguret: Still `var n=1; (n && n.hasOwnProperty("bar"))` does not raise an exception.

Comment: You have to check if the variable is an `object` first: `if (typeof bar == 'object' && ... `

Comment: If you want to be really sure, you could probably do something like: `if (data && data.hasOwnProperty && data.hasOwnProprety("error"))`

Comment: @hindmost: wrong, non-objects inherit the method also: `alert(1 .hasOwnProperty)`

Comment: @dandavis More precisely, you primitive value is boxed in an object (here an instance of Number) when you call a method on it. The primitive value doesn't have or inherit the method.

Comment: @DenysSéguret: another good reason to use `hasOwnProperty.call(5, "hasOwnProperty")` instead of owns, apparent or actual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Here's one:

```
var bar = Object.create(null);
```

Here's another one with `hasOwnProperty`, but not much better:

```
var bar = {hasOwnProperty:function(){ throw "bouh" }};
```

But you can call

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(bar, "foo")
```

Note that you may avoid the evaluation to truthy by doing

```
if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(Object(bar), "foo")) {
```

Comment: Thanks. Is that maybe the only case? How would you change my test to even cover that scenario?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke: Test that `.hasOwnProperty` is truthy first. So `if (data && data.hasOwnProperty && data.hasOwnProprety("error"))`

Comment: There are now three proposals for a safe test, right? i) `if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(Object(data), "error"))`. ii) `if (data && data.hasOwnProperty && data.hasOwnProperty("error"))` and iii) `if (typeof data == 'object' && data.hasOwnProperty("error"))`. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke mine ;)

Comment: @DenysSéguret: semantically, I like Matt's approach most. Does yours have technical advantages? Thanks for all the input already.

Comment: Null is the only value that has no default inherited properties correct?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Seriously: it doesn't really matter. The main point was to identify the risks and what needed to be done. Those ways to ensure it can't fail are basically equivalent. Mine is a little stronger as it also works if hasOwnProperty has been shadowed.

Comment: Thanks. Nice to point out the case of an overridden hasOwnProperty method. I guess I do not need to plan for this in my scenario, otherwise AngularJS is to be beaten.