# How does Object inside if condition works?

Tags: liferay-aui

I have seen people using this

```
            hideTooltip : function() {
               var toolRef = 'population_tooltip';
               if(Helper.tooltipObj[toolRef]){
                  Helper.tooltipObj[toolRef].hide();
               }
           }
```

The `Helper.tooltipObj[toolRef]` is an object. and i was wondering how is it working? can you put an object inside IF condition in Javascript(We are using AUI API)?

The function is called when someone clicks a button on a popup on the page(not the javascript alert type popup, kind of select some stuff and press OK popup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (expr)` - any expression is valid. If it evaluates to "an object" it is true as *all* Objects evaluate to a 'true expression' in this context. The expression is considered 'false-y' *only* for [undefined, null, false, "", 0, and NaN](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/).

Thus the condition only runs if "an object" (hopefully with said method) is assigned to the property - it would evaluate to undefined if no value had been previously assigned.

This logic assumes that any other 'true' (or even 'false') value is a prior programming error/contract breach and is a fairly common idiom.

---

See also:

- [Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)
- [All falsey values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript)