# Difference between exclamation equals sign and exlamation 2x equals sign when checking with null

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between next if statements in javascript when checking with **null**?

```
var a = "";
if( a != null ) // one equality sign
    ....
if( a !== null ) // two equality sign
   ....
```

When comparing to null I can't find any difference.

Comment: No difference when checking with null.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, `null` has type: `object` (try yourself executing the following sentence `typeof null`).

That is, `!==` will check that `a` is also `object` before checking if the reference equals.

Actually you know that `===` and `!==` are meant to check that both left and right side of the equality have the same type without implicit conversions involved. For example:

```
"0" == 0 // true
"0" === 0 // false
```

Same reasoning works on `null` checking.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

```
!=  - not equal
!== - not equal value or not equal type
```

Comment: W3Schools... NoOOooOOOooOOoo. The most hated Web development site!! hahaha

Comment: I don't think so, but nevertheless the explanation is simply enough to base on it

Answer (score 0):

`!=` checks

> negative equality

while `!==` checks for

> negative identity

For example,

```
var a = "";

a != false; //returns false since "" is equal false
a !== false; //returns true since "" is not same as false
```

but if you are comparing it with null, then value will be true in both ocassion since `""` is neither equal nor identical to `null`

Comment: I believe that these generic answers would be fine if OP would be asking for what's `===`. I guess OP wants to know what's the effect of `===` and `!==` when `null` is involved in the equality

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Thanks, I agree. Made the changes, please check.

Comment: Will be true, or false?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer It will be true for both since "" is neither equal nor identical to null

Comment: Yeah, I double-checked the answer and it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between them when comparing to **null**.

When we use [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Strict_equality_using) (**!==**) it is obvious because they have different types, but when we use [loose equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using) (**!=**) it is an *important thing to remember* about JavaScript language design.

Because of language design there are also some common questions:

- [How do you check for an empty string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)
- [Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "";
(1) if( a != null ) // one equality sign

Above condition(1) checks value only and not data-type, this will return true.

    ....
(2) if( a !== null ) // two equality sign

This checks value and data-type both, this will true as well.
```

To understand it more precisely,

```
var a = "1";

if( a == 1) {
    alert("works and doesn't check data type string");
}


if( a === 1) {
    alert('doesn't works because "1" is string');
}

if( a === "1") {
    alert('works because "1" is string');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference if variable has value undefined:

```
var a = undefined;

if( a != null ) // doesn't pass
  console.log("ok");

if( a !== null ) // passes
  console.log("ok");
```

Got idea from reading this great post [Why ==null, Not ===null](http://st-on-it.blogspot.si/2011/03/why-null-not-null.html). Also != is faster.