# Check If statement is true or false by using javascript Truthy and Falsy Value VS '===' operator

Tags: javascript

I have search a lot and i got multiple way to check if statement is true or false. I found the standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables is to use truthy value like.

```
  if(value) { }
```

[Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

I also found that the '===' operator is better to use over '==' operator.

[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

I need the shorter and save way for doing this. Now i am confuse with these two solution. Do i need to follow the standard way to check the statement is true or false or i need to use the '===' operator.

Comment: Simple answer would be, _It depends what you want to compare_. If it is just testing `true`/`false` values then `if(value)` is good enough.

Comment: You often see people use `==` in _JavaScript_ because they're used to the syntax from other languages. However, most people don't [_really know_ exactly what `==` does (even if they've read the spec)](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3), so I'd advise avoiding it; use `===` to compare and consider the _type_ of what you're trying to compare, e.g. a _String_ isn't a _Number_ so they are not equal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 3):

The standard when checking if a value is `null` or `undefined` ("blank" in your terminology) is to use `x == null`. This is short for doing `x === null || x === undefined`.

You will find that doing `x === null` doesn't actually work for checking `undefined`, since

```
null == undefined // true
null === undefined // false
```

There is a difference between checking for a "truthy" value and checking for `null` or `undefined`. However, both `null` and `undefined` are "falsey" values, so if all you want to do is check if your variable exists and is "truthy", then `if(x)` is fine. Note that certain things you might expect (without experience) to be true/false are not. For example:

```
'' == true // false
0 == true // false
```

Then there are some values that aren't "truthy" or "falsey". For example:

```
NaN == true // false
NaN == false // false
```

[Find a more complete list of weird stuff (and learn more about `==` vs `===`) in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons?lq=1).

<3 JavaScript

Comment: `NaN === NaN; // false` you can actually test for _NaN_ quite easily because of this by doing `x !== x`. Also note you get weird quirks with `==` like `1 == {toString: x => '1'}; // true`

Comment: Yeah. It's unclear if OP is more focused on `null`/`undefined`, `true`/`false`, or just `==`/`===`. If he cares more about `==`/`===` then for sure look at the question I linked to.

Answer (score 3):

> *use* === *for comparing the value as well as type.*
>
> *use* == *for comparing by values only*

```
// Example Program
var a = "0";
var b = 0;
console.log(a==b); // true
console.log(a===b); // false
```

Comment: Do you have a source for the quoted part of your answer? I think it does a great job cutting to the core of this often-misunderstood issue.