# Google Maps API for JavaScript isn't working properly when used in an AIR Android Project within StageWebView?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, air

I have been working with this for quiet some time now. I am now able to access values from Javascript within AS. But there are a couple of problems I am facing:

First, I am unable center the map on the user's location when the map is first opened. It works perfectly in an HTML file but doesn't work within StageWebView.

Second, I have also added the search UI which works wonders in html but not in StageWebView. I get hints of the typed string, but doesn't work when a location is selected.

What can I do to make it work?

Here is the html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <style type="text/css">
       html, body 
         {
             height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;
         }

  #map 
    {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .controls 
    {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }

  #pac-input 
    {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 300px;
  }

    #pac-input:focus 
    {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
  }

  .pac-container {
    font-family: Roboto;
  }

  #type-selector {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
  }

  #type-selector label {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
  #target {
    width: 345px;
  }

   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
  <script src="map.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? key=<MY_KEY>&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
     async defer></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Here is JS:

```
var marker;
var map;
var pos;
var ASLats;
var ASLngs;

window.initMap = function() {

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
{
center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
zoom: 15,
styles: [{
  featureType: 'poi',
  stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }]  // Turn off points of interest.
 }, {
  featureType: 'transit.station',
  stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }]  // Turn off bus stations, train stations, etc.
 }],
 disableDoubleClickZoom: false

 });

 var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
 var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
 map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
  searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
// Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and  retrieve
 // more details for that place.
 searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
 var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
   console.log(places);
 if (places.length == 0) {
   return;
};

  // Clear out the old markers.
  markers.forEach(function(marker) {
  marker.setMap(null);
});
markers = [];

  // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
places.forEach(function(place) {
  var icon = {
    url: place.icon,
    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
  };

    // Create a marker for each place.
  markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: icon,
    title: place.name,
    position: place.geometry.location
  }));

    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    // Only geocodes have viewport.
    bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
  }
 });
     map.fitBounds(bounds);

  });


  /* if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var pos = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
   };

   map.setCenter(pos);

     }, function() {
     handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
   });
    } else {

   // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
  // handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());

      alert(" Geolocation not supported on this browser ");

   }*/
        map.addListener('click', function(e) {

    SetMarker(0);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: {lat: e.latLng.lat(), lng: e.latLng.lng()},
     map: map
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:"Latitudes: " + e.latLng.lat() + " Longitudes: " + e.latLng.lng()
        });

    infowindow.open(map,marker);

    document.location.href = "hkjk:\\hgjyh.com?data=" + e.latLng.lat() + ","  + e.latLng.lng()+ "e" ;

    });
}


function SetMarker(position) {
//Remove previous Marker.
if (marker != null) {
    marker.setMap(null);
 }
}

function setMapCenter(lats, lngs){

ASLats = lats;
ASLngs = lngs;
pos = {
    lat: ASLats,
    lng: ASLngs
  };
   map.setCenter({lat:pos.lat, lng:pos.lng});
//map.setCenter(pos);
  alert("set map center function was called with " + pos.lat + " " + pos.lng);
}
```

related AS:

```
 private function showMap():void 
        {
            webView = new StageWebView();
            webView.stage = stage;
            webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0,  stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
            webView.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onWebViewLoaded, false, 0, true);
            webView.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onWebViewClicked, false, 0, true);

            trace("Loading Map");
            webView.loadURL(mapURL);
            trace("Map loaded!");
            /*webView.loadURL("javascript:setMapCenter('" +
            _lats + "', '" + _lngs + "')");*/
        }




 private function onWebViewClicked(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            webView.viewPort = null;
        }

        private function onWebViewLoaded(e:Event):void 
        {
            webView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING, getUpdate, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function getUpdate(e:LocationChangeEvent):void 
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            trace("Location: ", e.location);

            var result:String = e.location;
            latitudes = Number(result.substring(result.indexOf("=") + 1, result.indexOf(",")));
            longitudes = Number(result.substring(result.indexOf(",") + 1, result.indexOf("e")));

            trace(latitudes, longitudes);
        }
```

I can't write the entire application in JS or JAVA because , one, I have come way too far, I have written more than 15k lines of code spread across 65 classes, second, I don't really know JS or Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the map after loading it,add this line to your AS onWebViewLoaded function:

```
webView.loadURL("javascript:window.initMap()");
```

Comment: Do you know how to pass parameters?

Comment: webView.loadURL("javascript:window.initMap('" +
        param1 + "', '" + param2 + "')");

Comment: please set my answer as solution if that helped you

Comment: When I try to call a function named setMapCenter(lats,lngs); using your method. The function gets called, i don't get any error either but the map doesn't center it's position. When I call the function from inside JS, it works great.

Comment: So I am able to read the values inside JS. I really don't understand why this is not working. Can you please help me out?

Comment: I would need to see the code for that. Maybe open a new question

Comment: I have edited the JS code. Please check it out. When I call the setMapCenter(lats,lngs); from AS3 when stageWebView gets loaded. It works, the function gets called and I see the alert window with lats and lngs recieved from AS3. But when I use those values to center the map using map.setCenter(); .. It doesn't work.

Comment: when you call map.setCenter() from AS3 you must check if map is null. Map variable get instanciated inside of window.initmap so maybe is null at that point when calling from AS3 and is not when calling from JS

Comment: How do I check if the map is null? Also once the map has loaded , doesn't that mean it's not null?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in

Answer (score 0):

I think https://github.com/myflashlab/webView-ANE might solve your problems? It's a paid native extension though