# Comparing String to null or empty values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to create an if and else statement in JavaScript wherein if the string is empty, it will send out an alert box that all forms must be filled up. If not, the data grid in the webpage will increment with all the information entered on the form. But it seems that my code is not working properly. Below is my javascript code

```js
function addData(){ 
  if(document.getElementById("txt_description").isEmpty || document.getElementById("txt_update").isEmpty){
    alert("Missing information!!! Please fill up all the blank items"); 
  }else{
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
   
    cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("input_name").value;
    cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("input_blank2").value;
    cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("txt_description").value;
    cell4.innerHTML = document.getElementById("input_status").value;
    cell5.innerHTML = document.getElementById("input_pageable").value;
    cell6.innerHTML = document.getElementById("txt_update").value;
    
  }
}
```

Comment: So what does `.isEmpty` do, there's no such property natively?

Comment: `.isEmpty` exists in Java, but not JavaScript.

Comment: use string.length if it is less than 1 then it is empty...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your if statement to this:

```
if(document.getElementById("txt_description").value == ""|| document.getElementById("txt_update").value == "")
```

**.isEmpty** does not exist in javascript! If your input is empty, comparing it to an empty string will be sufficient!

For dealing with null values:

```
if(document.getElementById("txt_description").value == ""|| 
document.getElementById("txt_update").value == "" || 
document.getElementById("txt_description").value == null || 
document.getElementById("txt_update").value == null)
```

EDIT:

As mentioned in one of the comments, .value cannot be null. So you cold simply use the following if statement:

```
if(document.getElementById("txt_description").value == ""|| 
    document.getElementById("txt_update").value == "")
```

Comment: This won't work, because `document.getElementById` will return either an element or `null`, but never an empty string `""`, so it will always be false. I think you meant `document.getElementById().value`?

Comment: Edited @RobertAKARobin

Comment: Thank you James and Robert! I added what Robert commented on this post with your code and it is perfectly working now. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: `value` will never be `null`.

Comment: Yup i did! apparently there is this timer when I can click the check the "accepted" button. Thanks robert