# How to check ajax data.d is null in append?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append some data in html table using jquery that is working fine but when the data is null or empty i have to append another div to that html table.

**Am trying like this**

```
$("#table").append(data.d[i].one!=""?
    "<td id='divs'>
       <input id="+ data.d[i].one +" type=" + "checkbox" + " class=" + "cbCheck" + ">
       <label  for="+ data.d[i].one +"></label>
    </td>":"<div></div>");
```

but it is not working please help me how to fix this...

Comment: Your code is unreadable.

Comment: did you forget to add the `$` to the beginning or is it just a typo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check for an empty string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Comment: maybe you are accessing the `data` object wrong. try `console.log(data);`

Comment: i ll try it @Taha Paksu

Comment: actually am facing the problem is am appending multiple rows like this same data.d[i].two and three and so on ... so i am unable to use condition in every case i have to use condition in every case @Taha Paksu

Comment: can you provide a sample `data` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never understand why somebody use this

```
$("#table").append(data.d[i].one!=""?
    "<td id='divs'>
       <input id="+ data.d[i].one +" type=" + "checkbox" + " class=" + "cbCheck" + ">
       <label  for="+ data.d[i].one +"></label>
    </td>":"<div></div>");
```

Instead of this:

```
    //class declaration
    function YourTableCell(name, value) {
       this.input = document.createElement('input');
       this.input.value = value;
       this.input.name = name;
       this.label = document.createElement('label');
       this.label.text = 'My Label';
       this.container = document.createElement('td');
       this.container.appendChild(this.input);
       this.container.appendChild(this.label);
    }


    //application buisness logic
    if(data.d[i].one != ''){
      var cell = new YourTableCell(data.d[i].name, data.d[i].value);
      $("#table").append(cell.container);
    } else {
      $("#table").append(document.createElement('div'));
    }
```

Using this approach you can incapsulate table cell building inside of your class and make your code much more readable and reusable. Also, as I see now, you are trying to append `td` inside of something with id `#table`, and look like it is incorrect, because you should append `td` inside of `tr`.

Also, using this you can get references to all objects such as `input`s and avoid of $('input, select, textarea') selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
if( data.d ){
    //Your code
}
```

That will check if `data.d` is `NULL` or empty string `""`.

If you want to check in every iteration use the index `i` :

```
if( data.d[i] ){
    //Your code
}
```

Hope this helps.

Take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515349/4281779.

Comment: I think it should be `data.d`?

Comment: To be fair, it also checks for `undefined`, `0`, `NaN`, `false`, and other falsy values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this,

```
var html = '<div></div>';

if(data.d[i].one) {
    html = '<td id="divs"><input id="' + data.d[i].one + '" type="checkbox" class="cbCheck"><label  for="' + data.d[i].one + '"></label></td>';
}

("#table").append(html);
```