# How to show the error message when the textbox is empty when user click the submit button in ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-paper

I want to know when the textbox is empty and when user click the submit button the error message will need to show. Please help me.

This is my template register.hbs code

```
      {{paper-input
        label="E-mail"
        type="email"
        value=email
        onChange=(action (mut email))
        icon="email"
      }}

  {{#paper-button raised=true primary=true onClick=(action "register")}}Register{{/paper-button}}
```

and this is my controller register.js code

```
email: null,


actions: {
  register() {
    var data = {
      email: this.get('email'),
    };
    var record = this.store.createRecord('register', data);
    record.save().then((response) => {
      this.set('email', null);
      this.transitionToRoute('activation');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at http://offirgolan.github.io/ember-cp-validations/docs/modules/Usage.html. This is the best. And take a look at http://miguelcobain.github.io/ember-paper/release-1/#/components/input for using cp-validations in ember-paper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put something like:

```
if (!this.get('email').trim()){
  //your code to show some error message
  return
}
```

trim() removes possible whitespaces from the mail
and a empty or null string is falsy in javascript:

[More on trim](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp)

[More on what evaluates to True/False for strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515349/5796663)