# Stop executing if it is the case

Tags: javascript

```
$('.btn-process-request', node).bind('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = {};
  var fax_number_empty = {{ contract.request.customer.fax }}
  if (fax_number_empty == 0) {
    alert('Please, attach the fax number to your profile');
  }
  alert('Hello! What is your name?');
  if ($(this).data('reason')) {
      data.reason = prompt($(this).data('reason'));
      if (!data.reason.length && $(this).data('reason-required')) {
        alert($(this).data('reason-required'));
        return false;
      }
  }
  $.ajax({
    url : $(this).attr('href'),
    type: 'POST',
    data : data,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (data.success) {
          if (data.redirect_to) {
            window.location.href = data.redirect_to;
          }
          else if (data.reload) {
            window.location.reload();
          }
      }
      else {
        alert('Error! See console for details :(');
        console.error(textStatus, data);
      }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.error(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

In this code, I've created the lines

```
var fax_number_empty = {{ contract.request.customer.fax }}
      if (fax_number_empty == 0) {
        alert('Please, attach the fax number to your profile');
      }
```

I don't how to implement this correctly. I'd like say, ok, if `contract.request.customer.fax` is empty, then display an alert which will say 'Please, attach the fax number to your profile.' The most important thing here is to stop executing. In other words, what is bellow those lines would not be executed. Could anyone have time to tell me how to improve that code?

**P.S.** Please don't be shy to let me know if my question is unclear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

Comment: What's wrong with just adding an `else { ... }` so that what is in the `else` will only be executed if `fax_number_empty != 0`.

Comment: try ` fax_number_empty == null ` this checks if it's null and if `typeof(fax_number_empty) === "undefined"`

Comment: What do you mean? Put the bottom line between `{}` with the else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return in case the field `fax_number_empty` is a  [falsy value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript)  , and the function will jump to the end avoiding the rest of the code.

```
   if (!fax_number_empty) {
     alert('Please, attach the fax number to your profile');
     return; 
   }
```