# Run only if string value is not set, is running every time

Tags: javascript, screeps

I am trying to run a block of code only if the varaibles are not valid strings (length > 0, and not undefined). Based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in) I think Im doing it right, but this runs every time. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    if (creep.memory.sourceid ||creep.memory.depositLoc||creep.memory.sourceType)
    {
        creep.memory.sourceid = getSourceMinWorkers(creep);
        creep.memory.sourceType='energy';
creep.memory.depositLoc=getClosestDepositLoc(creep.memory.sourceid,creep.memory.sourceType);
        console.log(creep.name," harvesting ",creep.memory.sourceType," at: ",creep.memory.sourceid," depositing at: ",creep.memory.depositLoc);
    }
```

output of console.log:

```
H1_1  harvesting  energy  at:  81a61f68f5eb4057223b05b2  depositing at:  a7633d25d9058f616ab8a0f3
H1_1  harvesting  energy  at:  1649baad43f736c9fc13d2ad  depositing at:  a7633d25d9058f616ab8a0f3
```

Comment: Have you tried logging out `creep.memory.sourceid` etc. as soon as you enter the `if` block? At least one of those values must be truthy (not `false`, `undefined`, `null`, or an empty string). You can [easily verify this for yourself.](https://jsfiddle.net/ohnyfyxq/)

Comment: You can create a more simple example to get to the bottom of this. Your specific game code is not important to the task.

Comment: @sheriffderek Their code seems pretty simple to me. What they're missing is information about what those three values truly are.

Comment: I just think for the best outcome - something that is simplified is best - also for other people in the future - something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/d31mj4Lu/  - also, we don't have context for where this is happening in a function.

Comment: @sheriffderek Simpler may be better but their code is definitely simple enough. Where it's happening doesn't really matter. It's a matter of what values each property contains and which boolean operators are used.

Comment: And the people make their cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking with a OR (`||`) operator. That means that the conditional will run if either of the conditionals is true (non-empty in case of strings).

You have this conditional:

```
if (creep.memory.sourceid || creep.memory.depositLoc || creep.memory.sourceType) {
```

It means that if `creep.memory.sourceid` is set OR `creep.memory.depositLoc` is set OR `creep.memory.sourceType` is set, it will run.

I see that you are logging the 3 variables with this line:

```
console.log(creep.name," harvesting ",creep.memory.sourceType," at: ",creep.memory.sourceid," depositing at: ",creep.memory.depositLoc);
```

The data is logged each time the block is ran, and I see that the 3 parameters are non-empty strings, so the code is working as expected.

By your code, I think that the expectation is to run the code only if 2 parameters are set but there's no location, so you have to switch your OR operators to AND (`&&`), which will pass if ALL 3 conditionals are true. Also you will have to check if the location is empty, like this:

```
if (creep.memory.sourceid && !creep.memory.depositLoc && creep.memory.sourceType) {
//    Notice the exclamation ^ up there
```

This way the code block will be ran if there's a source id AND if DON'T(`!`) has a deposit location AND if has a source type. Notice the exclamation before the location parameter. This means that is the negation of the value.