# Variadic Function in Java Script

Tags: javascript

I have a js function as below

```
function showMsg(id) {
      id = id! = null && id != undefined ? id : '';
      //doing some task
    }
```

I am calling above function from two different event one with parameter and another without parameter as below,

Call from first event,

```
showMsg(id);
```

Call from second event

```
showMsg();
```

As i know JS function is variadic in nature so is it right way to call the function?
Will it cause any problem in older version of brwoser?

Any  help and suggesstion must be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: This will be fine even in ancient browsers. You may or may not only want to check for only `undefined`. And take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shorten it to

```
id = id || '';
```

All falsy values are converted to an empty string. So as `undefined`, which is the value for calling the function without a parameter.

Comment: This will change `showMsg(false)` , `showMsg(null)` and `showMsg(0)` to `showMsg("")` (which is probably okay here, and if it is, it would also be my preferred idiom).

Answer (score 1):

Validate with simple `If(id)` is enough. it validate `undefined`, `empty`,`null` also and `!` refer for `id` is a false then stop the function execution .validate empty spaces use with `if(id.trim())` => [`trim()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiI0unbgI3UAhVJrY8KHVfZCyMQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_trim_string.asp&usg=AFQjCNEDh_x7JMeCVu0sakhKLDvxAVHYaw&sig2=wdK1jXxSnmEbkMumGR4i2A) function

```js
function showMsg(id) {
      if(!id){
       return false
      }
      //doing some task
      return id;
    }
    console.log(showMsg('hi')) //with argument
    console.log(showMsg()) //without argument
```