# Retrieve the session value and pass as required parameter of api Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session

I want to retrieve the session value and pass that value as required parameter for the api. My session is `$_SESSION['name']`. And these are my codes

```
var uniqueName = **Here I want to retrieve session value**;
  if(**Then I want to check if uniqueName is null or undefined**) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://api/check.php',
      type: 'GET',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType:'json',
      data: {
        name: uniqueName
      },
      success: function(result) {
        alert("Success");
      },
      error: function(result) {
        alert("Error");
      }
    });
  }

  return false;
});
```

Comment: In addition to the answer below, for your `if(**Then I want to check if uniqueName is null or undefined**)` ... just do `if (typeof uniqueName != 'undefined' && uniqueName !== null)` ... but since you have `var uniqueName = '';` above that, it will never be undefined ;)

Comment: In addition to @Randall comment above, you could use `uniqueName.length > 0` as your conditional instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put PHP directly into your JS, like

```
var uniqueName = '<?php echo isset($_SESSION['name']) ? $_SESSION['name'] : '' ?>';
```

In JS will be name or empty string.

---

If you haven't this JS in PHP file, you can pass a session using AJAX call, or assign to any HTML element.

```
<input type="hidden" id="session_var" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['name']) ? $_SESSION['name'] : '' ?>">
```

And in JS file then:

```
var name = document.getElementById('session_var'); // name from session or empty string.
```

Comment: If his JS is in a dedicated .js file included in the head, then he would have to do an ajax call to grab the session name value, with a promise to wait for its return before sending it off to the second ajax. OR he stuffs it into a basic html element that the js will pull from by element id and attr. Couple ways to go about it.

Comment: Could you please provide an example for that? @Randall

Comment: @F.Duh for what? If it's really JS file, easiest is to write SESSION into any element in HTML like `<input type="hidden" id="session_var" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['name']) ? $_SESSION['name'] : '' ?>">`. In JS then `var name = document.getElementById('session_var').innerHTML;`

Comment: What @panther said. Easiest is to insert it into hidden html elements. I do this a lot because ALL of my .js files are minimized and cached into the headers. I put all kinds of things in elements for js to grab at :D

Comment: @F.Duh I've updated my answer for the HTML/JS mix. AJAX request is another method, but these two are fine for you too.

Answer (score 0):

```
var uniqueName = "<?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?>";
  if(uniqueName) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://api/check.php',
      type: 'GET',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType:'json',
      data: {
        name: uniqueName
      },
      success: function(result) {
        alert("Success");
      },
      error: function(result) {
        alert("Error");
      }
    });
  }

  return false;
});
```

References:

[Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/scalar.php

Comment: This is no different than the other answer.

Comment: When I tried to do like this `var uniqueName = "<?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?>";` as you mentioned above, the `uniqueName` is always `<?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?>`. What I really want to retrieve is the actual name like `Lorem` or something to pass that `uniqueName` as the required parameter of the api.

Comment: Where are you trying to run the script??

Comment: go to http://phpfiddle.org/ and run the following piece of code and you will be able to see it works.                                                                            <?php
$_SESSION['name'] = 'test';
?>
<script>
var uniqueName = "<?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?>";
    alert(uniqueName);
</script>

Comment: Thanks @Rohit. My script is on the separated js file.

Comment: Yes, I saw panther's solution. Happy Coding :)