# How to check if atleast one key value of a array contains a specific string

Tags: javascript

I have an object as :

```
testArray = [{SId: 1, CModule: "End"},
             {SId: 2, CModule: "Slice"},
             {SId: 3, CModule: "Std"}]
```

How to return true if any of the `CModule` value is 'End' or return false

I have tried as :

```
      testArray .map(function (CModule) {
        if (CModule.CModule.indexOf('End')!==1) {
          return true;
        }
        else{ return flase } };
```

But this did not work when there is no value as 'End' or if it has no 'End' in its first index value

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: [Maybe this would help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49077991/how-can-i-check-if-an-object-contains-at-least-one-key-whose-value-contains-a-su)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for checking if atleast one element pass the condition.

```js
let testArray = [
  {SId: 1, CModule: "End"},
  {SId: 2, CModule: "Slice"},
  {SId: 3, CModule: "Std"}
];

let res = testArray.some(item => item.CModule === 'End');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution , The same can be done using a simple for loop ? just curious to know how to

Comment: Yes! It's a prototype of ```Array```. So you can apply this any kind of array. For more information, you can visit this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: The same I am checking if it contains 'End'.....as testArray.some(item => item.CModule.indexOf('End')!==-1)....Am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Why do you need ```indexOf```?  It's not wrong though.

Comment: I m checking if value contains 'End' instead equalling it....if indexOf('End')!==-1 which certainly would give false if doesn't contain...so im using it

Comment: If you need to check if ```End``` is a substring then it's okay. The ```some``` checks if the function inside it returns a true or false value. It's totally upto you how could you check if it returns true or false.

Answer (score -1):

The below code should work:

```
<script>
var testArray = [
             {SId: 1, CModule: ""},
             {SId: 2, CModule: "Slice"},
             {SId: 3, CModule: "Std"},
             {SId: 4, CModule: "End"}
             ];

      testArray .map(function (CModule) {
        if (CModule.CModule.indexOf('End')!==1) {
        console.log('true');
          return true;
        }
        else{ console.log('false');
        return flase 
        } 
        });

</script>
```