# Javascript - if ( variable ) to check for 'undefined' is failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, undefined

```
if( !body || body[0] === '<') {...}
```

I am using the above statement to check if a variable `body` is `undefined` or null or anything but the value that is expected, but I keep getting a TypeError:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

How can this be? According to the very popular answer on checking for undefined the first part `!body` of the above statement should return `true`  if body is anything from null, undefined, NaN, "", 0, or false - and therefore not evaluate the right-hand side of the OR condition: `body[0] === '<'` when that is the case.

[Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in/5515349#5515349)

What else could I check for to make sure that `body[0]` is only called when `body` is not undefined? I also already tried `if(typeof body === 'undefined' || body[0] === '<')` with the same described behaviour. Any thoughts on this will be highly appreciated. Thanks you.

(Just for further information: `body` is the response of an REST-API request, if everything goes smooth it returns a string that can be parsed into a JSON-object. However, in some cases an entire HTML-file (containing error information) is returned hence I'm checking for '<' at the beginning of the response. Sometimes the variable seems to be 'undefined' which throws the error when checking `body[0]`.)

Comment: Are you sure the error is thrown in that line, and not one line down inside the `if` where you try to access `body[0]` again?

Comment: I think something else is going on.  [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y5qpk0av/2/) showing your code working fine under several conditions

Comment: @deceze is on to something, `!body` should shortcut in `if (!body || ..`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the logic backwards.

```js
function isFirstCharLt(value) {
  return !!value && typeof value === 'string' && value[0] === '<';
}

console.log(isFirstCharLt(undefined));
console.log(isFirstCharLt(null));
console.log(isFirstCharLt('<string'));
console.log(isFirstCharLt('string'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not showing us all the codez ;)

The code block will be run if `body` is `undefined` since it shortcuts `||` in the if statement and I suspect you're checking `body[0]` somewhere in that code block.

```
if (!body || body[0] === '<') {
  // is body[0] used here? 
}
```

It's better to make sure `body` has the correct properties, e.g.

```
if (typeof body === 'string' && body[0] === '<') {}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would use two if statements, check if its defined first then validate:

```
if(body) {
  if (body[0] !== '<') {
    'DO-SOMETHING'
  }
}
```

Comment: You can condense that to `if (body && body[0] ...)`, and then you basically have what OP already has.

Comment: but its not what he already has, what he has isnt working

Comment: But it *should*, that's the issue. First understand why it *isn't* working.

Comment: because its undefined which is why i am validating that high level then  validating the content of the body. there is definitely a more intricate way of doing this but this would work