# How to find falsy value in array?

Tags: javascript

I require to return either true or false on a conditional basis. If my array contains a `empty, null, undefined,""` I require to return false. else true.

Is there any easy and correct way to return like ?

Here is what I am looking for :

```
var ar = ["apple", '', undefined, null ]; //false
var ar = ["apple", 'Orange', undefined, null ]; //false
var ar = ["apple", 'Orange', "gova", null ]; //false

var ar = ["apple", 'Orange', "gova", "mango" ]; //true
```

How to find the falsy and truthy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

Comment: why down vote here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if there is at least one falsy element in it. Then negating the result should get you what you want.

```js
var ar = ["apple", 'Orange', "gova", null ]; //false
console.log(!ar.some(t => !t));
ar = ["apple", 'Orange', "gova", "mango" ]; //true
console.log(!ar.some(t => !t));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
!ar.some(element => !element);
```

Explained:

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array
>   passes the test implemented by the provided function.

The expression `!element` coerces the value to a boolean, so falsy elements become `true` and truthy elements become `false`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 0):

You could check every item with [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/) as callback for all [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) elements.

```js
function check(array) {
    return array.every(Boolean);
}

var array = [["apple", '', undefined, null], ["apple", 'Orange', undefined, null], ["apple", 'Orange', "gova", null ], ["apple", 'Orange', "gova", "mango"]];

console.log(array.map(check));
```