# JavaScript runtime error: '[MethodName]' is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use jQuery and AJAX to validate that users entered a number in a particular field and that they didn't leave it blank and I'm a little confused as to why I can seem to do one, but not the other.

I'm doing this in a jQuery `change()` function so any time they change the value in that field, it updates it in the database without refreshing the whole page and it works fine until I try to use `isNull()` to validate.

I'm saving their input to a variable called `UserInput` and first checking to make sure it's a number with this:

```
if (!isNaN(UserInput))
```

which works perfectly. I'm also trying to check and make sure it isn't empty by using this:

```
if (isNull(UserInput))
```

Intellisense completes `isNull()` for me just like it did for `isNaN()` and all appears well in Visual Studio, it compiles without error. I've also tried `isNullOrUndefined()` here with a similar result, intellisense completes it for me and all seems well. Right up until I change the value in the field, at which point it promptly gives me this error:

*JavaScript runtime error: 'isNull' is undefined.*

I'm not sure why it's undefined (especially since intellisense is completing it for me) or how to go about defining it.

I also tried this because it seemed like it covered all the bases, not just `isNull()`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515349/8767826

and I put an `alert()` inside the `if` and I didn't get an error, but my alert didn't fire either.

The end goal is to get it to change to a zero on the client side if they leave do leave it blank.

Anyway I'm kind of stumped and I appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Thanks

Comment: you can easily check if($('#id_of_your_input').val().length == 0) {alert('required'); return; }

Comment: *"I'm not sure why it's undefined"* `isNull` is not a built-in JavaScript function.

Comment: Unless you've defined the `isNull()` and `isNullOrUndefined()` functions in JS, then your Intellisense is lying to you. They are not standard JS functions. Assuming you're referring to Intellisense in Visual Studio, then I would ignore everything it tells you for JS. It is notoriously unreliable.

Comment: *"The end goal is to get it to change to a zero on the client side if they leave do leave it blank."* `UserInput = UserInput === '' ? 0 : Number(UserInput)` (still needs an `isNaN` check).

Comment: Also, `and all appears well in Visual Studio, it compiles without error.`. JS is **not** a compiled language. JS is considered an `interpreted language`, that is, JS code is not looked at by the browser until that line is ran.

Comment: @Rich: That's not quite true. The browser certainly *parses* the code before it is executed. I.e. if I have `function foo() { ( }` then this will immediately result in a syntax error, even though the function is never executed.

Comment: @Rich javascript is not a **pre** compiled language.  It is indeed compiled though.

Comment: For reference, check out [String.IsNullOrEmpty in JavaScript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5572/string-isnullorempty-in-javascript).

Comment: What other libraries are you using in your project? Do you also have underscore there?

Comment: @FelixKling No need for the ternary, `Number('') === 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for an `isNull` function; you can check

```
if (UserInput === null)
```

`isNaN` exists because `NaN`, unlike every other value in JavaScript, is not equal to itself.

**But `null` doesn't mean the field is blank!** If the field is blank, its value will be the empty string. Check for that instead:

```
if (UserInput === '')
```