# Why does JavaScript's logical AND (&&) not work the same as an if conditional?

Tags: javascript, node.js, conditional-statements

I've been doing JS development for a long time now, and for years I thought I could short circuit a conditional statement using the logical AND.  In fact, I do this ALL THE TIME in my React components with conditional rendering.  But it turns out it doesn't work the way I would expect all the time.  The question is, why?

Here is an example for Node 8.15.0:

```
> a = 0.0
0
> a && console.log(a)
0
> if(a) console.log(a)
undefined
> !!a && console.log(a)
false
```

Specifically, why does `a && console.log(a)` not work the same as `if (a) console.log(a)`

Comment: What behavior are you expecting? All of those look correct to me. If the problem is the `undefined`, many JS repls print `undefined` when you give it a statement that doesn't return a value (like an if statement)

Comment: It works exactly as I expect it. What did you expect?

Comment: Value 0 is not equal True. `a && console.log(a)` is one-liner and it means: `if (a==true) { console.log(a) }` ... check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515349/4415165

Comment: `falsey && val` evaluates to  `falsey`. `truthy && val` evaluates to `val`. What do you expect instead? And why?

Comment: Specifically why does `a && console.log(a)` not evaluate the same as `if (a) console.log(a)`

Comment: Because one is an expression, the other a statement. `var result = a && console.log(a)` makes perfect sense. `var result = if (a) console.log(a)` not so much. So why would you expect the two to exhibit the same behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if(a) ...` is a *statement*. `a && ...` is an *expression*.

This behaviour is specific to a console. If a line evaluates to an expression, the result outputted, otherwise it's considered that a line was evaluated to `undefined`.

`a && ...` is a [short-circuit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation). This means that if `a` is falsy, the expression evaluates to `a`. If `a` is truthy, the expression is evaluated to `...`.

This doesn't affect the way both are used in real application instead of a console. If the result of the evaluation isn't used, both `if` and short-circuit evalution act the same way, i.e. evaluate `...` only if a condition is truthy.

Comment: Oh yes!  The answer is that if it evaluates to falsey, it returns the left side of the expression.  THANK YOU!!

Comment: @DaKaZ It doesn't always return the left side, it returns *the first falsey value*. For example, `true && "Hello World" && 0 && false` would be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

`!!` operator convert variable to boolean.
In your case `a` equal to `0` so it will convert it to `false`, and because of this you see `false` as output for `!!a && console.log(a)`

Answer (score 0):

**The first expression** outputs 1 line to the console, which is what the statement evaluates to:

```
a && console.log(a)
0
```

The expression clearly evaluates to the value of `a`. That's because this [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) can be considered equivalent to the following conditional ternary:

```
a ? console.log(a) : a
```

**The second expression** evaluates to `undefined` because it is not an actual expression but a block construct. With braces this time:

```
if (a) { console.log(a) }
undefined
```

**The third expression** is quite similar to the first one, except that this time not the value of `a` is returned but the value of the sub-expression `!!a`, or `false`:

```
!!a && console.log(a)
false
```

---

**Note** If `a` would be a *truthy* value both the first and third statements would evaluate to `undefined`, the return value of `console.log`.