# Is there a standard way to deal with option (something that may return a null) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a standard way to return "Option" (an object that may be null) in Javascript?

For example, is there a more standard way to handle a piece of code like this, especially the function `GetById(userId)`?

```
class User {
  static function GetById(userId) {
    if (userId === 'A_GOOD_ID') {
        return new User('GOOD_NAME');
    }
    return null;
  }

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

function authenticate(userId) {
  const user = User.GetById(userId);
  if (user) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: `return !!(User.GetById(userId));`? In general you can deal with false-y values using [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) and [the conditional  operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: `if (user)` is the standard way. Need to take care if you want to accept falsey things like `0`, but otherwise works and is very concise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

Answer (score 2):

That's the standard way, returning null is preferable rather than, for example, throwing an error.

When you use the function, you should check if the returned value is truthy:

```
const result = User.GetById(...);
if (!result) {
  // handle error
}
```

Or you can use the shorthand `or`:

```
User.GetById(...) || handleError();
```

which is less readable, in the opinion of many.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the conditional operator `expression ? value_if_true : value_if_false` for a more concise code. For example:

```
static function GetById(userID) {
    return userId === 'A_GOOD_ID' ? new User('GOOD_NAME') : null;
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
static function GetById((userID) => userID === 'A_GOOD_ID' ? new User('GOOD_NAME') : null;
```

The same applies for your `authenticate` function:

```
return user ? true : false;
```

As for checking using `if (user)`, it's a pretty standard way to check if an expression is truth-y or not false-y.