# JavaScript: How to check if object method has valid result

Tags: javascript

I have a very basic question but I couldn't find any similar questions. I have the following code:

```
var admin_li = helper.h('li', [fpu_link('/admin', 'control', false)]);
if (Discourse.User.current().admin) {
    menu_li.push(admin_li);
}
```

I get the following error in the DevTools:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'admin' of null
```

How can I check if the `Discourse.User.current()` has a property/method of `admin` in the `if` statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a method chained with a property? `Discourse.User.current().admin` or is it `Discourse.User.currentProp()` or `Discourse.User.current('admin')`?

Comment: @zer00ne `if(document.getElementById('foo').classList.contains('bar') === false) { }` you see it every day.

Comment: @Kaiido derp indeed I do, the obvious is always the least remembered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of this should work for you:

```
var admin_li = helper.h('li', [fpu_link('/admin', 'control', false)]);
// Get current from user and store in local variable
var currentUser = Discourse.User.current();

if(currentUser !== null && currentUser !== undefined) {
  // If currentUser not null and not undefined then it's safe to access
  // the admin field
  if (currentUser.admin) {
    menu_li.push(admin_li);
  }
}
```

Alternatively (as suggested by @MarkMeyer), the code above can be written in a more concise shorthand form as follows:

```
if(currentUser && currentUser.admin) {
  // If currentUser is "truthy" (not null, not undefined, etc), and 
  // currentUser.admin is "truthy", then update menu_li list
  menu_li.push(admin_li);
}
```

See [this more information on the definition of "truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (and ["falsey"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)) values in JavaScript

Comment: What if `undefined`?

Comment: It's probably more idiomatic to use `if (currentUser && currentUser.admin) { /*...*/}` and save yourself some nesting.

Comment: @MarkMeyer yeah I had considered that but decided against that approach for the sake of maximum clarity

Comment: @MarkMeyer thanks for your suggestion - I've just extended the answer to include that