# check if string is undefined or empty

Tags: javascript

how can I simplify this function in javascript:

```
checkMyString() {
  if (myString === undefined) {
    return false;
  } else if (myString === '') {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: return !!myString

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `undefined` and `''` are falsy values, you can just check if the values are not falsy with `!!` operator. Read more here [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

```js
// undefined
!!myString
// => false

// empty string
!!myString
// => false
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `||` operator

```
checkMyString() {
  if (myString === undefined || myString === "") {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Or you could just directly return an expression

```
checkMyString() {
  return !(myString === undefined || myString === "");
}
```

If you want to check for all falsy values i.e `0`, `false`, `""`, `undefined`, `null` and `NaN` then you can simply use `Boolean`

```
checkMyString() {
  return Boolean(myString)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just depend on the truthy value and coerce it to a boolean if you absolutely want it to be a boolean:

```js
function checkMyString(str) {
  return !!str;
}

let myStr = undefined;
console.log("Checking: undefined", checkMyString(myStr));

myStr = "";
console.log("Checking: '':", checkMyString(myStr));

myStr = null;
console.log("Checking: null:", checkMyString(myStr));

myStr = "my string";
console.log("Checking string value", checkMyString(myStr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as you check if a string has some value in vanilla javascript:

```js
function checkMyString(myString) {
  return myString ? true : false;
}

// Result: false
console.log(checkMyString());

// Result: false
console.log(checkMyString(undefined));

// Result: false
console.log(checkMyString(null));

// Result: false
console.log(checkMyString(''));

// Result: true
console.log(checkMyString('Value'));
```

Comment: You can use `Boolean(myString)` instead of `myString ? true : false;`