# Returning an object only if all of its values are non-null

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an object in which the value of each field is retrieved with an individual call:

```
let ExampleObj = {
  foo: getFoo(),
  bar: getBar(),
  baz: getBaz(),
  ...
}
```

I have a function that will return the object if and only if all fields evaluate as non-null:

```
let returnsExampleObj = () => {
  // if (!!ExampleObj.foo && !!ExampleObj.bar && !!ExampleObj.baz) {
  //   return ExampleObj
  // } else {
  //   return undefined
  // }
}
```

I can obviously just manually check each field to see whether it's null or not like in the above example, but is there a more elegant way of doing this? There may be dozens of fields in this object and to check each one manually would be very tedious.

Comment: When you say "evaluate as non-null", what do you mean? Do you mean truthy (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check that `.every` of the values are truthy:

```
const returnsExampleObj = () => {
  return Object.values(ExampleObj).every(Boolean) ? ExampleObj : undefined;
};
```

Comment: Problematic with `{ intval: 0 }`? Not clear the OP wants int zero to be treated like null/undefined. Also empty string and NaN potentially problematic, depending on what the OP actually wants.

Comment: He's using `!!`, which sounded like it's working for his purposes. Sure, if it's an issue, strictly compare against null instead. `.every(val => val !== null)`

Comment: Yup, unclear spec here - you will need to charge the OP another $2500 if the spec changes ;-)