# How do I inform the Typescript compiler that every value of an object has been checked and is defined?

Tags: typescript

I have the following object whose values are retrieved dynamically. Each function call (`getFoo`, `getBar`, etc) can either return a value or `undefined`.

```
let ExampleObj = {
  foo: getFoo(),
  bar: getBar(),
  baz: getBaz(),
  ...
} 

const getFoo:()=>Foo|undefined = () => {...}
...
```

As per an answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66556876/returning-an-object-only-if-all-of-its-values-are-non-null), I'm using `Array.every` to check that each value in the object is defined, returning undefined if there is even a single undefined value, i.e -

```
type ExampleObj = {
   foo: Foo
   bar: Bar
   baz: Baz
}

const returnsExampleObj:ExampleObj|undefined = () => {
  let exampleObj = {
    foo: getFoo(),
    bar: getBar(),
    baz: getBaz(),
  } 
  return Object.values(exampleObj).every(val => val != undefined) ? exampleObj : undefined;
};
```

However, the Typescript linter is unable to infer that I've performed this check so it complains that I'm returning an invalid type (since ExampleObj values can never be undefined). Do I just have to `//@ts-ignore` this away, or is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: You can do `exampleObj as ExampleObj` when returning to assert the type. If the object is dynamic and eg, passed as an argument, you could use generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler will not be able to look at your implementation and conclude that `exampleObj` has no `undefined` properties.

While you as a human being understand that [type guarding](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the array that comes out of  `Object.values(obj)` has implications for the type of `obj`, there is no way to express such a relationship in TypeScript.  Generally speaking, type guarding one value in TypeScript can only have an effect on the apparent type of that value itself (or, if you're checking the discriminant property of an object whose type is a  [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), it can have an effect on the apparent type of that object).  While it would be nice to be able to propagate type guarding through other operations, it would have a devastating impact on compiler performance if you tried to actually implement that.  As mentioned in a comment on [microsoft/TypeScript#12185](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184), a request for a similar feature,

> This would require us to track what effects a particular value for one variable implies for *other* variables, which would add a good deal of complexity (and associated performance penalty) to the control flow analyzer.

So if the compiler can't figure it out by itself, we have to tell it.

---

If you are only going to write the `Object.values(obj).every(...)` test  once in your code base, then the best you will be able to do is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
const returnsExampleObjAssert = (): ExampleObj | undefined => {
    let exampleObj = {
        foo: getFoo(),
        bar: getBar(),
        baz: getBaz(),
    }
    return Object.values(exampleObj).every(val => val != undefined) ?
        exampleObj as ExampleObj : undefined;
};
```

By writing `exampleObj as ExampleObj`, we're saying to the compiler "please treat `exampleObj` as if it is a value of type `ExampleObj`."  The compiler just believes you, because it is unable to figure out the truth one way or the other.  So be careful not to lie to the compiler (e.g., `Object.values(exampleObj).some(val => val != undefined) ? exampleObj as ExampleObj : undefined).

---

If you are likely to perform this test multiple times on different objects, it might make sense to write a user-defined type guard function whose return type is a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) of the form `arg is Type`.  When you call such a function, the compiler will understand that a `true` result implies that `arg` can be narrowed to `Type`, and a `false` result implies that this narrowing cannot take place (and sometimes that a different narrowing can take place that *excludes* `Type`).  Here's how I might do it for your test:

```
function allPropsDefined<T extends object>(
    obj: T
): obj is { [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], undefined> } {
    return Object.values(obj).every(v => typeof v !== "undefined");
}
```

The function `allPropsDefined()` takes an argument named `obj` of a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) object-like type `T`. The implementation returns a `boolean` value; either `true` if all of `obj`'s properties are defined, or `false` if that is not true.  The return type, `obj is { [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], undefined> }`, is a type predicate, which is assignable to `boolean`.  That type `{ [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], undefined> }` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  It has the same keys as `T`, but the properties are modified; for each property key `K`, the property type at that key, `T[K]`, has `undefined` excluded from it via [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion).  So if `T[K]` is `string | number | undefined`, then `Exclude<T[K], undefined>` is `string | number`.

Let's test it out:

```
const returnsExampleObjTypePredFunc = (): ExampleObj | undefined => {
    let exampleObj = {
        foo: getFoo(),
        bar: getBar(),
        baz: getBaz(),
    }

    return allPropsDefined(exampleObj) ?
        exampleObj // let exampleObj: { foo: Foo; bar: Bar; baz: Baz; }
        : undefined;
};
```

This now compiles with no error.  You can see that in the true clause of the ternary conditional operator, `exampleObj` has been narrowed from `{foo: Foo | undefined, bar: Bar | undefined, baz: Baz | undefined}` to `{foo: Foo, bar: Bar, baz: Baz}`, which is assignable to `ExampleObj` as desired.

Again, if you're doing that test just once or even twice, the overhead of a type predicate function is probably not worth it.  But if you might do it a bunch of times in your code base, a type predicate function might pay for itself.

And again, the compiler is unable to verify that your type guard function is properly implemented.  I could change `every()` to `some()` and the compiler will be just as happy.  All the compiler can really check is that the return type matches `boolean`.  So we still need to be careful not to lie to the compiler.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIyYBcyAzmFKAOYDcuAvrqJLIigEJxQ76EAjHmUrUQ9Ji3DR4SZNwBefQsiEKRVWg2a4E6EJWQ0IYDOjIAKAJTIAvAD40mZAB9kAVxAATCDFAQvO2RrO0cAWTgwAAsAOig4b3QAWxCAHmQABhiADgB2AFZkAH4cIlJkACJidArkRmQyTx8-EACGPQMwIxNuKEsbB3keVw9vX39A22CB8MjY+MSUm3SsvMKS7FVhSqEoWvrGsZa23X1DYzBFftChpTcm8dbJ6ZuI6LiEr2S0zJyC4tKajIFTU+wao2aEwYuDAAE8AA4oACiAA84El4QAbCAAeQEACsgngVNUyGZ+ARdmRehStupbpJTp1kFATO4oAZUeisbiCQBBcjkaBdKbWMhcjHYvGE+5HCY3YmEbFdCBoyW8wlTRUqAik7qmTDWAA0tJUVP1vWNpsEcHpF0UVpUzBUrLA7JAyGlEAQYBiADc4Jj3BByBZVdypQSrDEIH7oLCLAHMTck8gAIRTB7HLw2IrWgjh9XS5BwcjICU84uHSFPbTQ3AwTw+4D6EuYzEABSg6Hh5AAIo8AqkACrIVWQbxl9AE71gewWWnT-FkYe4KxkJfIYBlzYAbQA0luPQBrCCw9AwZDDgC64pRCCDPhHB+vRohg68jnq2pZbI5npnH1-UDYNQyXaNY3jRMbjhREL2QP101sKYKizCYKisbRcGwjpDFdd1yArSN8WHBEIC7AJUCbIIxXLNVKwJEY0KeBVaWVMd6OIol8zKcx9TMR0dUpbZ7R4QShKBC1bXEupsJdP8PUDTtu17AdszDTiNVzHjCwYwkAHp9OQdjdOIshNj1Mw6C2PohigazJMUaznSE8FmJORhoRMhgvmUQgUCmfCOUIzTpVIxEKK8KiQAQaxtGQAB3KJgGxYI0wgKwcLOdBsRiTF0BoMMYjUYrbRiMB0AAVXhREoAAYVLCBrEw5BDPkPkAC1sKAA)

Comment: An incredibly thorough and informative answer, thank you! I wasn't aware of Typescript utility types like `Exclude` -- very useful when used in conjunction with type predicates.