# How does a odd num value and 1 gives 'true' in js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I went through a simple problem, but its solution got me confused.

```js
function modifyArray(nums) {
    // i & 1 will be 1, or true, if 'i' is odd
    return nums.map(i => (i & 1) ? i * 3 : i * 2);
}


console.log(modifyArray([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

In the above code,(i&1) returns true or 1 if i is an odd number.

How does this work, can anyone please explain?

Comment: All numbers but zero are [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in/5515349#5515349)

Comment: [bitwise AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND)

Comment: The binary representation of any odd number ends with `1` while that of any even number ends with `0`. The binary representation of `1` is many `0`s and a `1`. `&` is the Bitwise AND Operator so it calculates the AND of each bit. For any other positions because one side is `0` you always get zero. But for the last bit one side is `1` so it'll produce `1` when other side ends with `1` too, and `1` is truthy. Else it produces `0` and it is falsy.

Answer (score 1):

The expression (n & 1) will always return true for positive odd numbers, since the Least Significant Bit (LSB) will be set for these values.

So the result will be

```
         xxxx1
AND (&)  00001
--------------
Result   00001
```

The result will always be 1, which is [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

You can demonstrate this by logging the binary representation of each value to the console:

```js
let nums = Array.from({ length: 10}, (v,k) => k + 1);
console.log("Nums:", JSON.stringify(nums))
console.log("Nums.map (binary):", JSON.stringify(nums.map(num => num.toString(2).padStart(4, '0'))))
console.log("Nums.map (binary, LSB):", JSON.stringify(nums.map(num => +num.toString(2).slice(-1))))
console.log("Nums.map (num & 1):", JSON.stringify(nums.map(num => (num & 1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments already said, you are doing an bitwise AND. Think of the binary representation of each number and compare each digit with an AND to get the resulting digit. Here are some examples:

`1&1` (both values have a binary `1` in the last column)

```
  0001
& 0001
= 0001
```

`2&1` (there is not a single `1` in the same column for both numbers)

```
  0010
& 0001
= 0000
```

`5&1` (both values have a binary `1` in the last column)

```
  0101
& 0001
= 0001
```

`6&1` (there is not a single `1` in the same column for both numbers)

```
  0110
& 0001
= 0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit operators (&, |, ~, ...) work on 32 bits numbers. Any numeric operand in the operation is converted into a 32 bit number. The result is converted back to a JavaScript number. For example

x = 5 & 1 is same as 0101 & 0001 which is equal to 0001 and in decimal it is 1

You may refer to binary equivalent of numbers here https://www.javatpoint.com/binary-numbers-list

Answer (score 0):

The Array in Binary:

```
0 = 0000
1 = 0001
2 = 0010
3 = 0011
4 = 0100
5 = 0101
```

AND Results:

```
0 & 1 => 0000 AND 0001 = 0000 => False
1 & 1 => 0001 AND 0001 = 0001 => True
2 & 1 => 0010 AND 0001 = 0000 => False
3 & 1 => 0011 AND 0001 = 0001 => True
4 & 1 => 0100 AND 0001 = 0000 => False
5 & 1 => 0101 AND 0001 = 0001 => True
```

`i & 1` will always look at the first bit and see if it is a 0 or a 1. So all odds will have a 0 while all evens will have a 1

Answer (score 0):

& is `bitwise and`. Everything is a bit under the hood.

**Examples for numbers up to 3 digits**:

```
0 = 000
1 = 001
2 = 010
3 = 011
4 = 100
7 = 111
```

When we do `bitwise and` of 1 and say, 3, we are doing `AND` between each digit of `001` and `011`, which returns 1.
For, `100` and `001` it returns 0.

This bitwise and is good shortcut to find odd numbers as the last digit of **bitwise representation** of every odd number is 1.