# How to hide specific HTML table column?

Tags: javascript, typescript, html-table

I have a dynamically made HTML table. I want to hide one of the columns with style.visibility = "hidden"

The cell i want to hide is provided with the needed ID, but when i do this my whole table disappears.

```
// get element ID & set to hidden
document.getElementById('wachtwoord')!.style.visibility = 'hidden'

// set ID of the cell & append to DOM
 Object.values(userData).forEach((userDataElement, columnIndex) => {
      // create element and textnode      
      let cell: HTMLTableDataCellElement = document.createElement("td");
      let textNode: Text = document.createTextNode(userDataElement as string);

      // append to DOM   
      cell.appendChild(textNode);
      row.appendChild(cell);
      table.appendChild(row);
      createTable!.appendChild(table);

      row.id = userData.id

      if (columnIndex === 3) {
        cell.id = "wachtwoord"
      };
```

How can i hide a specific table cell?

Comment: `HTMLElement.hidden = true` check [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden).

Comment: @Jax-p thanks for the input but still the whole table disappears

Comment: You may want to try `display: none;` attribute

Comment: Why are you using the exclamatory mark `'!'` in your code written above?
as far as I know, we don't use the exclamatory mark there.

Comment: @Babis.amas still the whole table disappears instead of column

Comment: @groovy_guy because i get an error the object is possibly null which isn't and with the ! you say it can't be null

Comment: @uuuuuuray are you sure you are targeting the proper element?

Comment: @uuuuuuray this is not how we check a null element. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515349/15405352) for details

Comment: @Babis.amas yes unfortunately, otherwise the table wouldn't disappear at all i think

Comment: You should provide some code so that we can have a look at it.

Comment: @Babis.amas i've editted the code

Comment: Are the row, table, createTable variables initialized previously?