# JavaScript checking for nullish value as part of an if block?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to check for nullish values as part of an if block, without resorting to a pair of explicit checks for `null` and `undefined`.

For example, don't want to do this:

```
if(key === null || key === undefined) {
    // do something
}
```

This doesn't work, because it also includes other falsy values such as zero and empty array.

```
if(!key)
```

Comment: An empty array is not falsy. There’s the `??` (nullish-coalescing) operator and there’s the `==` operator. There’s also `Object.hasOwn`. What is done with `key`? The best alternative depends on more context.

Comment: There's a long discussion with multiple approaches https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in

Answer (score 10):

That's one of the good use cases of the operator `==`:

```js
if(key == null) {
    // do something
}
```

This will work with both null and undefined, while keeping away other falsy values.

Comment: While indeed `undefined == null` is true `undefined !== null` is true as well.

Comment: While this is clearly a working answer in any codebase maintained by more than one person I would strongly question the readability of this code. The maxim that code is read more than written is true. JS has a bunch of quirks and I'd just avoid falling back on them altogether.

Comment: @丶Limeー来夢丶 `!==` is the negated version of `===`, `undefined != null` is false as one would expect