How to check if a variable is not null and not empty string or not whitespace in JavaScript?
I need to check if a string variable is

not null
not undefined
not empty string and
not whitespace in JavaScript

I originally did this,
if (testData && testData.trim() !== '') {

Resource: trying to simplify off this opposite question
How to check if a variable is null or empty string or all whitespace in JavaScript?

You could make this slightly more compact, but it's debatable whether that would actually be "better". Assuming you know that testData is either null or a string, what you have looks fine.

undefined and false isn't a concern?

hi @zer00ne I just added string variable,  added undefined in criteria above

Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in

What exactly is your question? The code you got seems to work.

You already have found that other questions, with answers like this. Do you not know how to negate a boolean(ish) value in JavaScript?

You can use the ! symbol along with .trim() to do this compactly.  The ? is used to make sure an error doesn't occur if the value is null and you try and .trim() a null value.  It basically doesn't run the .trim() if the value is null or undefined


var testData = '    '
if (testData?.trim()) {
//Stuff that happens if not WHITESPACE/empty/null
console.log('null1')
}
testData = null
if (testData?.trim()) {
//Stuff that happens if not WHITESPACE/empty/null
console.log('null2')
}
testData = ''
if (testData?.trim()) {
//Stuff that happens if not WHITESPACE/empty/null
console.log('null3')
}



